# Is there a cross-platform way of getting information from Python's OSError?

Tags: python, exception, cross-platform

On a simple directory creation operation for example, I can make an OSError like this:

(Ubuntu Linux)

```
>>> import os
>>> os.mkdir('foo')
>>> os.mkdir('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'foo'
```

Now I can catch that error like this:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.mkdir('foo')
>>> try:
...     os.mkdir('foo')
... except OSError, e:
...     print e.args
... 
(17, 'File exists')
```

Is there a cross-platform way that I can know that that the 17 or the 'File Exists' will always mean the same thing so that I can act differently depending on the situation?

(This came up [during another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/python-best-way-to-create-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist-for-file-write).)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `errno` attribute on the error should be the same on all platforms. You will get `WindowsError` exceptions on Windows, but since this is a subclass of OSError the same "`except OSError:`" block will catch it. Windows does have its own error codes, and these are accessible as `.winerror`, but the `.errno` attribute should still be present, and usable in a cross-platform way.

Symbolic names for the various error codes can be found in the `errno` module.
For example,

```
import os, errno
try:
    os.mkdir('test')
except OSError, e:
    if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
        # Do something
```

You can also perform the reverse lookup (to find out what code you should be using) with `errno.errorcode`. That is:

```
>>> errno.errorcode[17]
'EEXIST'
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to then reraise the original exception if it wasn't `EEXIST`.

Comment: @ford Can you post an answer testing if directory exists first and then rerraising error after creation attempt? This is all seems overly complicated. In Linux I would use `mkdir -p ~/.config/mserve` for my purposes. I'm not sure what the `~` equivalent is in Windows though. It's hard to believe stack overflow doesn't have a definitive answer for creating a directory in Python...

Comment: The first part of your question is answered here, I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/600612/576932