# Python: Creating directories

Tags: python

I want to create a directory (named 'downloaded') on in my desktop directory; isn't this working?:

```
import os
os.mkdir('~/Desktop/downloaded/')
```

Comment: If the Desktop dir is in other language????? how to locate on Desktop in any language?

Comment: For code that does the equivalent of "mkdir -p" see http://stackoverflow.com/q/600268/319741

Answer (score 15):

You can't simply use `~`  You must use [os.path.expanduser](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to replace the `~` with a proper path.

Comment: So you could replace that code with `os.mkdir(os.expanduser('~/Desktop/Downloaded/'))`.

Comment: @Leafstorm `os.path.expanduser`, not `os.expanduser`.

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
import os
os.mkdir(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/downloaded"))
```

The `~` character is a POSIX shell convention that represents the contents of the HOME environment variable. So, when you type in a shell:

```
$ mkdir ~/Desktop/downloaded
```

it's the same as typing

```
$ mkdir $HOME/Desktop/downloaded
```

Try changing the HOME environment variable to verify what I say.

Since it's a shell convention, it's something that neither the kernel treats specially, nor Python, and the python `os.mkdir` function is just a wrapper around the kernel `mkdir(2)` system call. As a conveniency, Python provides the `os.path.expanduser` function to replace the tilde with the contents of the HOME env var.

```
$ HOME=/tmp  # it is already exported
$ python
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Mar  2 2010, 00:28:19) 
[GCC 4.3.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.expanduser("~/dada")
'/tmp/dada'
```

Answer (score 2):

another way, use `os.environ`

```
import os
home=os.environ["HOME"]
path=os.path.join(home,"Desktop","download")
try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except IOError,e:
    print e
else:
    print "Successful"
```