# Create folder tree dynamically from a string

Tags: python, django

I am working on code in which I will create folders and sub folders based on a string retrieved from the database. It's dynamic; it could be one level, two levels, or ten.

I'm trying to replace the dots with slashes and create the proper tree, but this code below won't do the job:

```
for x in i.publish_app.split('.'):
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, PATH_CSS_DB_OUT) + x + '/'):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, PATH_CSS_DB_OUT) + x + '/')
```

`i.publish_app` is, for example, `'apps.name.name.another.name'`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
os.makedirs(path[, mode])
```

> Recursive directory creation function.
>   Like mkdir(), but makes all
>   intermediate-level directories needed
>   to contain the leaf directory. Raises
>   an error exception if the leaf
>   directory already exists or cannot be
>   created. The default mode is 0777
>   (octal). On some systems, mode is
>   ignored. Where it is used, the current
>   umask value is first masked out.

Straight from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs).

Comment: thanks mate. I don't know how I missed that, Python is really something :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `os.makedirs()`, there is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python) if you need it to behave like `mkdir -p`.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you just doing:

`os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, PATH_CSS_DB_OUT,x,"")`

(The last `,""` is to add a `\` or `/` at the end, but I don't think you need it to make a directory)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Python 3.5, there is [`pathlib.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir):

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
nested_path = path / ( PATH_CSS_DB_OUT + x)
nested_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

This recursively creates the directory and does not raise an exception if the directory already exists.

(just as [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=makedirs#os.makedirs) got an `exist_ok` flag starting from python 3.2 e.g `os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)`)