# How do I check for a certain type of OSError in a try except block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I have some code that potentially could raise an `OSError` based on the user's input. More specifically, it could raise `OSError: [WinError123]`. The problem I'm facing is that my try except block checks for `OSError` which is way too broad of an exception.

I've looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973418/os-mkdirpath-returns-oserror-when-directory-does-not-exist/22718321#22718321) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753686/a-more-elegant-way-to-control-overwriting-with-try-except-else-in-python-or-can) however, it's unclear to me how `errno` works. I've also looked at the `errno` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/errno.html#errno.EEXIST) but it is unclear to me how it relates to the specific errors within `OSError`.

How do I catch a specific `OSError` namely, `WinError 123`?

Also if you could explain to me what libraries you utilized / how you did it / the thought process of your solution would be wonderful!

Comment: Catch the WinError and check the errno https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.WindowsError

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ok the errno is 22. So is the only way to catch this specific error is to add an if statement in my except block? Is there no code like `except OSError.WinError123:` ?

Comment: Yep, this is the documentation  for python3 https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/exceptions.html#OSError.winerror https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/exceptions.html#WindowsError

Comment: no, you need to catch the general exception then check the errno

Comment: Ok gotcha. I tried doing `except NotaDirectoryError:` but that didn't work.

Comment: Is  a windows error 123 not a `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`?

Comment: I think `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` is apart of the win32api. Is that built into python?

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/twisted/python/win32.py and this https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/twisted/python/filepath.py#L333

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105938/discussion-between-dzhao-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 3):

Can you not do something like:

```
try:
    my_function()
except OSError as e:
    if e.args[0] != 123:
        raise
    print("Deal with the 123 error here")
```

Comment: I get the following output when I tried that:     `os.chdir(paths)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: ''` So I think the code you proposed might not work? B/c it didn't ignore WinError123

Comment: How can I replicate this error? Edit: Nevermind. I was able to do it. The `errno` is 22, but the `e[0]` is 123.

Comment: See my discussion with Padraic in OP comment section. errno is 22 determined from experimentation.

Comment: Well, I've updated it. It doesn't use errno and it only selects WinError 123.

Comment: It seems for python 3 (and 2.7?) you need to use `if e.winerror != 123:`