# Is there a simple method for mkdir that is more than one directory deep unmade?

Tags: python

Assume I only have the folder `/root`, with no subdirectories.  Is there an easy method in python to create all directories for the following (in one line) `/root/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/foo.exe?`

Comment: Seems identical to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

os.makedirs()

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs

Comment: Can os.makedirs work when called with the file at the end, as well?

Answer (score 3):

os module:

```
os.makedirs('/root/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/')
```

[docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html)