# What is the difference between makedirs and mkdir of os?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I am confused to use about these two `os`methods to create the new directory.

Please give me some example in Python.

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) for `os.makedirs()` explains the difference. Did you read it?

Comment: **NB!** The above link leads to the Python 2 documentation. In Python 3 `os.makedirs()` is more *powerful* and has additional parameters, like `exists_ok` (since version 3.2) etc: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.html#os.makedirs

Answer (score 155):

`makedirs()` [creates all the intermediate directories](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) if they don't exist (just like `mkdir -p` in bash).

`mkdir()` can create a single sub-directory, and will throw an exception if intermediate directories that don't exist are specified.

Either can be used to create a single 'leaf' directory (dirA):

- `os.mkdir('dirA')`
- `os.makedirs('dirA')`

But makedirs must be used to create 'branches':

- `os.makedirs('dirA/dirB')` will work [the entire structure is created]

`mkdir` can work here *if* `dirA` already exists, but if it doesn't an error will be thrown.

Note that unlike `mkdir -p` in bash, either will fail if the leaf already exists.

Comment: this answer needs editing because `os.makedirs()` will throw exception if directories already exist, so it is not like `mkdir -p`

Comment: os.makedirs(new_path, exist_ok=True) will not throw exception

Comment: [_As an addition to the above comment_] The `exists_ok` parameter is available since Python **version 3.2**: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.html#os.makedirs

Answer (score 30):

(Can not comment, just add to NPE's answer.)

In Python3, `os.makedirs` has a default parameter `exist_ok=False`.
If you set it to `True`, then `os.makedirs` will **not** throw any exception if the leaf exists.
(While `os.mkdir` doesn't have this parameter.)

Just like this:

`os.makedirs('dirA', exist_ok=True)`

P.S.
You can type `?` before the name of a method in IPython shell to take a quick look at the documentation.
e.g.:

```
>>> import os
>>> ? os.makedirs
```

Answer (score 1):

makedirs : Recursive directory creation function. Like mkdir(), but makes all intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory. Raises an error exception if the leaf directory already exists or cannot be created.