# When should I use pathlib.Path.mkdir() vs os.mkdir() or os.makedirs()?

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory, pathlib

According to python 3.6 documentation, a directory can be created via:

1. [`pathlib.Path.mkdir(mode=0o777, parents=False, exist_ok=False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir)
2. [`os.mkdir(path, mode=0o777, *, dir_fd=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20mkdir#os.mkdir)
3. [`os.makedirs(name, mode=0o777, exist_ok=False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20mkdir#os.makedirs)

Questions:

1. It looks like `pathlib.Path.mkdir()` does most of what `os.mkdir()`
   and `os.makedirs()` do. Is `pathlib.Path.mkdir()` a "modern"
   implementation of both `os.mkdir()` and `os.makedirs()`?
2. When should I use `pathlib.Path.mkdir()` vs `os.mkdir()` or `os.makedirs()`? Any performance differences?

Please explain in relation to POSIX considerations. Thanks.

Comment: It seems as if `os.mkdir` is the simplest solution. Given the python philosophy, I suppose the simplest method would be the most preferable.

Comment: Difference of `os.mkdir` and `os.makedirs`: [What is different between makedirs and mkdir of os?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819496/what-is-different-between-makedirs-and-mkdir-of-os).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`mkdir` does not create intermediate-level directories that are not existent at the time of function calling. `makedirs` does.

`Path.mkdir` also does, but it's called as a method of a Path object (whereas the other two are called receiving the path, be it by a string with the path or a Path object (starting on Python 3.6), as an argument to the function).

Otherwise, behavior is the same.

Comment: `(Path.mkdir())[https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir]` has a parameter called `parents` which is passed `False` by default. If you pass `True`, then any parent of the path is not there those will be created. Usage: `pathObj.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)` will create the path parts which are not there and if some parts are there then it won't raise the `FileExistsError` exception.