# Creating folders from text file

Tags: python

I am trying to create folders from the context of a text file.

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as x:
    for line in x:
        line= line.strip().split()
        filename= "_".join([i for i in line])
        os.mkdir(filename)
```

this code works as long as file is like this;

```
1
2
3
4
```

But my text file contains more stuff, moreover it has "-" string, and I'd like to create subfolders in these folders. Text file as follows:

```
1 - a
2 - b
3 - c - d
4 - e - f - g
```

In the end I'd like to have 4 main folders (1,2,3,4) and in these folders there needs to be a,b,c,d,e,f,g subfolders. I'm trying to get folders like this;

```
1\a
2\b
3\c\d
4\e\f\g
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello nespressoX :) try instead of `os.mkdir(filename)` use `os.makedirs()`

Comment: Side note: `[i for i in line]` is equivalent to `line`...

Answer (score 1):

this will create nested dirs...

```
from pathlib import Path
with open("filename.txt", "r") as x:
    for line in x:
        dirs_list = [i.strip() for i in line.split('-')]
        Path(*dirs_list ).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Sorry to be annoying, one last thing :) there is no need to do `line.strip()` as you already `strip` each element (`i.strip()`) of the `split()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by using `os.makedirs()`

[What is different between makedirs and mkdir of os?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819496/what-is-different-between-makedirs-and-mkdir-of-os#:%7E:text=makedirs()%20creates%20all%20the,os.)

```
import os 

with open('filename.txt','r') as x:
    for line in x.read().splitlines():
        spl = line.strip().split('-')
        directory = os.path.sep.join([s.strip() for s in spl])
        #print(directory)
        os.makedirs(directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this loop to help you with your problem:

```
import os

def make_and_ender(folder_name):
    os.mkdir(folder_name)               # Make folder based on folder name given
    os.chdir(folder_name)               # Move into that folder

with open("filename.txt", "r") as x:    # Open file for reading
    content = x.read()                  # Load entire file into 1 large string
    lines = content.splitlines()        # Split into lines
    current_path = os.getcwd()          # Get the current working directory (The folder including 1,2,3,4)
    for line in lines:
        folder_list = line.split(" - ") # Make a list out of the line, splitting the string up based on the-
        for folder in folder_list:      # " - " format (search split up if your not sure )
            folder_name = folder_list[folder_list.index(folder)] # Get the name of the next folder in the list
            make_and_ender(folder_name) # call the function (make_and_enter)
        os.chdir(current_path)          #return to the current path (The folder including 1,2,3,4)
```