# Does the `shell` in `shell=True` in subprocess means `bash`?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I was wondering whether `subprocess.call("if [ ! -d '{output}' ]; then mkdir -p {output}; fi",shell=True)` will be interpreted by `sh` or`zsh` instead of `bash` in different server?

Anyone has ideas about this?

What should I do to make sure that it's interpreted by `bash`?

Comment: It means - use the default shell - whatever that default is

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, Jon! But what should I do to make sure that it's interpreted by bash?

Comment: @Firegun Call `/usr/bin/env bash` and feed it your commands as input.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

> ```
> On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh
> ```

Note that /bin/sh is often symlinked to something different, e.g. on ubuntu:

```
$ ls -la /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar 29  2012 /bin/sh -> dash
```

You can use the `executable` argument to replace the default:

> ... If shell=True, on
>   Unix the executable argument specifies a replacement shell for the
>   default /bin/sh.

```
subprocess.call("if [ ! -d '{output}' ]; then mkdir -p {output}; fi",
                shell=True,
                executable="/bin/bash")
```

Answer (score 4):

To specify the shell, [use the executable parameter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) with `shell=True`:

> If shell=True, on Unix the executable argument specifies a
>   replacement shell for the default /bin/sh.

```
In [26]: subprocess.call("if [ ! -d '{output}' ]; then mkdir -p {output}; fi", shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
Out[26]: 0
```

---

Clearly, using the executable parameter is cleaner, but it is also possible to call bash from sh:

```
In [27]: subprocess.call('''bash -c "if [ ! -d '{output}' ]; then mkdir -p {output}; fi"''', shell=True)
Out[27]: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly invoke the shell of your choice, but for the example code you posted this is not the best approach.  Instead, just write the code in Python directly.  See here: [mkdir -p functionality in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python)