# Execute curl with parameters- Python 2.6.6

Tags: python, linux, shell, curl

I have the following command executed in the linux shell:

```
$ curl -s -K <\(echo user = "$AUTH") "${URI%/}"
```

where AUTH and URI are environment variables.
I have tried to execute the command with python program in several ways:

1.

```
import os
b = os.popen('curl -s -K <(echo user = $AUTH) $URI').readlines()
```

2.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(
    ['curl -s -K <(echo user = $AUTH) $URI'],
    shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
)
```

but I always receive an error of this kind

```
"sh: 1: cannot open (echo: No such file"
```

or

```
"sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected".
```

It seem to me there is a problem with the escaping of the special symbols. Can you help me with this one?

Comment: python is using `/bin/sh` to run your command and `/bin/sh` doesn't support process substitution. You need to manually use `/bin/bash` instead (or see if you can get python to use `/bin/bash` for `subprocess.call`).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15449428/258523

Answer (score 0):

run your command in:

```
cmd = "curl -s -K<conf_file> -u 'username:password' 'www.something.com'"

os.system(cmd)
```