# How to run os.mkdir() with -p option in Python?

Tags: python, mkdir

I want to run `mkdir` command as:

```
mkdir -p directory_name
```

What's the method to do that in Python?

```
os.mkdir(directory_name [, -p]) didn't work for me.
```

Comment: Try os.makedirs('/multiple/path/')

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mkdir -p functionality in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can try this:

```
# top of the file
import os
import errno

# the actual code
try:
    os.makedirs(directory_name)
except OSError as exc: 
    if exc.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(directory_name):
        pass
```

Comment: exc doesn't have errno attribute.

Comment: That should be os.mkdirs (the ending s is important), but SO won't let me submit such a small edit.

Comment: This does not do the same as "mkdir -p":
```-p, --parents: no error if existing, make parent directories as needed```

Comment: @Hugo edited the answer so that it now uses the `makedirs` function, thus working like `mkdir -p`

Comment: Edited. `exist_ok=True` is much simpler than checking errno and ignoring certain exceptions.

Comment: rolled back to cover python 2.7

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `else raise`? An `if` statement with a `pass` body does nothing.

Answer (score 24):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs), you can now use this since python 3.2

```
os.makedirs("/directory/to/make", exist_ok=True)
```

and it will not throw an error when the directory exists.

Comment: This also creates missing parents. Nice!

Answer (score 13):

Something like this:

```
if not os.path.exists(directory_name):
    os.makedirs(directory_name)
```

UPD: as it is said in a comments you need to check for exception for thread safety

```
try:
    os.makedirs(directory_name)
except OSError as err:
    if err.errno!=17:
        raise
```

Comment: That's an inherent race condition 7and therefore a *very* bad idea.

Comment: this is prone to race conditions. Ie, if some other process/thread creates `directory_name` after the `if` but before the `os.mkdirs`, this code will throw exception

Answer (score 11):

If you're using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html), use `Path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)`

```
from pathlib import Path

new_directory = Path('./some/nested/directory')
new_directory.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

`parents=True` creates parent directories as needed

`exist_ok=True` tells `mkdir()` to not error if the directory already exists

See the [`pathlib.Path.mkdir()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir).

Answer (score -5):

how about this 

`os.system('mkdir -p %s' % directory_name )`

Comment: Avoid running unnecessary shell commands if you don't have to