# subprocess.Popen gives random result

Tags: python, shell

I wrote a simple piece of code:

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen('mkdir -p ./{a,b,c}', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
p.wait()
```

Unfortunately, it not always behaves the way I'd expect. I.e, when I run it on my PC, everything is OK (ls -l gives me three dirs: a, b and c). But when my colleague runs it on his desktop, he gets... one dir named: '{a,b,c}' ... We both use Python 2.7.3. Why is that? How would you fix it?

I tried to find the answer by myself. According to manual:
"args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string. By default, the program to execute is the first item in args if args is a sequence. If args is a string, the interpretation is platform-dependent and described below. See the shell and executable arguments for additional differences from the default behavior. Unless otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass args as a sequence."

So I tried to execute the code in shell:

```
python -c "import subprocess; p=subprocess.Popen(['mkdir', '-p', './{ea,fa,ga}'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT); p.wait()"
```

And I got:

```
mkdir: missing operand
```

I will be thankful for any advice

Thanks!

Comment: What operating systems are you (and your colleague) running it on? If both linux, what shells are you using?

Comment: Different shells might give different results.

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029871/how-to-run-os-mkdir-with-p-option-in-python

Comment: @endragor I don't think this is a duplicate. This question is about the `./{a,b,c}` syntax, not the `mkdir -p` command itself.

Answer (score 2):

The `./{a,b,c}` syntax is `bash` syntax, not supported by all shells.

The documentation says:

> On Unix with `shell=True`, the shell defaults to `/bin/sh`. If args is a
>   string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell.

So your command only works if `/bin/sh` is symlinked to a shell that supports that syntax, like `bash` or `zsh`. Your colleague is probably using `dash` or another shell that doesn't support this.

You should no be relying in something like a user's default shell. Instead, write the full command with the full expansion:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('mkdir -p ./a ./b ./c', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several problems here.

- First: if you are using a sequence of arguments, do not set "shell = True" ([this is recommended in the Popen manual)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor). Set it to False, and you'll see that your mkdir command will be accepted.
- "./{a,b,c}" is AFAIK a specific syntax in bash. If your colleague is using a different shell, it will probably not work, or behave differently.
- You should use the python "mkdir" command instead of calling a shell command, it will work whatever the server / shell / OS.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.
It seems, that the best way is simply use /bin/sh syntax. I changed my code to use:

```
'mkdir -p ./a ./b ./c'
```

as you suggested.

I avoided to use mkdir() function, because I am writing a scripts with plenty of system calls, and I wanted to provide elegant --dry-run option (so I could list all of the commands).

Problem solved - thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The os.mkdir(path,[mode]) method are as far as I understand safer to use when working on multiplatform projects.

```
os.mkdir(os.getcwd()/a)
```

However its not as elegant as taking the subprocess approach.

Comment: Your code doesn't work, you need to use quotes: `os.getcwd() + "/a"`.
This also don't answer the specific OP's question.