# How do I write a unit test for OSError?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage, python-unittest

I have the following python code which I want to test:

```
def find_or_make_logfolder(self):
    if not path.isdir(self.logfolder):
        try:
            makedirs(self.logfolder)
        except OSError:
            if not path.isdir(self.logfolder):
                raise
```

I want to do something like the following in my unittest.

```
def test_find_or_make_logfolder_pre_existing(self):
    with self.assertRaises(OSError):
        makedirs(self.logfolder)
        find_or_make_logfolder()
```

However, `if not path.isdir(self.logfolder):` is checking if the directory already exists or not so that the `except OSError` will only be thrown in some edge case where a program or person succeeds in making the directory a few milliseconds after the `if` and before the `try`.

How do I test this, or do I really need to test this?

I tend to like it when coverage says 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go a more Pythonic route to achieve this. In Python the philosophy is

> It's better to ask for forgiveness than to ask for permission.

See [EAFP here](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)

With that in mind, your code could be written as follows:

```
def find_or_make_logfolder(self):
    try:
        makedirs(self.logfolder)
    except OSError:
        #self.logfolder was already a directory, continue on.
        pass
```

Now to get 100% of this code covered, you will just need to create a test case where the directory already exists.

Answer (score 4):

[`mock`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) library is a must-have tool for achieving a 100% coverage.

Mock out `make_dirs()` function and set a [`side_effect`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/#quick-guide) on it:

> side_effect allows you to perform side effects, including raising an
>   exception when a mock is called

```
from mock import patch  # or from unittest import mock for python-3.x

@patch('my_module.makedirs')
def test_find_or_make_logfolder_pre_existing(self, makedirs_mock):
    makedirs_mock.side_effect = OSError('Some error was thrown')
    with self.assertRaises(OSError):
        makedirs(self.logfolder)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm late posting here, but I wanted to share my solution (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16029908/501277)), and also include my `mock`ed unit tests.

I made a function to create a path if it doesn't exist, like `mkdir -p` (and called it `mkdir_p` to facilitate my remembering it).

**my_module.py**

```
import os
import errno

def mkdir_p(path):
    try:
        print("Creating directory at '{}'".format(path))
        os.makedirs(path)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(path):
            print("Directory already exists at '{}'".format(path))
        else:
            raise
```

If `os.makedirs` is unable to create the directory, we check the `OSError` error number.  If it is `errno.EEXIST` (==17), and we see that the path exists, we don't need to do anything (although printing something could be helpful).  If the error number is something else, e.g. `errno.EPERM` (==13), then we raise the exception, because the directory is not available.

I'm testing it by mocking `os` and assigning error numbers to `OSError` in the test functions.  (This uses a file **tests/context.py** to allow easy importing from the parent directory, as suggested by [Kenneth Reitz](https://github.com/kennethreitz/samplemod/blob/master/tests/context.py).  Although not directly related to the question, I'm including it here for the sake of completeness.)

**tests/context.py**

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

import my_module
```

**tests/my_module_tests.py**

```
import errno
import unittest

import mock

from .context import my_module

@mock.patch('my_module.os')
class MkdirPTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_with_valid_non_existing_dir(self, mock_os):
        my_module.mkdir_p('not_a_dir')
        mock_os.makedirs.assert_called_once_with('not_a_dir')

    def test_with_existing_dir(self, mock_os):
        mock_os.makedirs.side_effect = OSError(errno.EEXIST, 'Directory exists.')
        mock_os.path.isdir.return_value = True
        my_module.mkdir_p('existing_dir')
        mock_os.path.isdir.assert_called_once_with('existing_dir')

    def test_with_permissions_error(self, mock_os):
        mock_os.makedirs.side_effect = OSError(errno.EPERM, 'You shall not pass!')
        with self.assertRaises(OSError):
            my_module.mkdir_p('forbidden_dir')
```

Comment: I don't think this example "assigns error numbers", the error numbers are passed as args, which doesn't do anything special. Python 3.6.9: `In [1]: err = OSError(os.errno.EEXIST)`, `In [2]: err.errno is None` `Out[2]: True`, `In   [3]: err.args` `Out[3]: (17,)`

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of other situations that raise OSError, e.g. filesystem full, insufficient permissions, file already exists etc.

In this case permissions is an easy one to exploit - simply arrange for `self.logfolder` to be set to a nonexistent directory for which your process does not have write permission, e.g. in *nix assuming that you do not have write permission in the root directory:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.makedirs('/somedir')
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/somedir'
```

Also, consider Martin Konecny's suggested refactor.

Comment: p.s. This just bit me on a unittest. Someone ran the test suite and the exception was not raised. Their box has major issues and this may assume non-insane permissions- but it is still an assumption and one proven to be false. I now am explicitly setting up a temp dir with guaranteed no permissions.

Comment: The assumption was mentioned in the answer. Using /root was just a suggestion because it is a known directory that non-root users _shouldn't_ be able to write to. Might be better to look at mock as suggested by alecxe

Comment: Yeah, I basically rolled something similar, made a temp dir and set the permissions manually. I wasn't using /root in my test, I used a fake dir (/should/not/exist or some such).