# Trying to use open(filename, 'w' ) gives IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory if directory doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, create-directory

I am trying to create and write to a text file using Python. I have searched and cannot find a solution/reason for this error.

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
afile = 'D:\\temp\\test.txt'
outFile = open(afile, 'w' )
outFile.write('Test.')
outFile.close()

# Error: 2
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\temp\\test.txt' #
```

Most answers I found related to the slashes in the path, so...

```
I tried 'D:/temp/test.txt' and got an error.
I tried r'D:\temp\test.txt' and got an error.
```

When I try to create a file at the root of D:/ I have success.

```
'D:/test.txt' works.
'D:\\test.txt' works.
r'D:\test.txt' works.
```

**It seems that I can't create the directory path I would like while trying to create the file**. What is the correct method for creating files at a specific path with Python on Windows(7)? Am I misunderstanding what open() can do? Does it create directories if they don't exist or do I need to explicitly create the directory path before I use open() in 'write' mode to create a file?

Comment: open doesn't create directory
check this answer for solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/create-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist-for-file-write

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You are correct in surmising that the parent directory for the file must exist in order for `open` to succeed. The simple way to deal with this is to make a call to [`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs).

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs):

> **os.makedirs(path[, mode])**
>
> Recursive directory creation function. Like `mkdir()`, but makes all intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.

So your code might run something like this:

```
filename = ...
dirname = os.path.dirname(filename)
if not os.path.exists(dirname):
    os.makedirs(dirname)
with open(filename, 'w'):
    ...
```

Comment: When you're dealing with the filesystem, [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) is always better than [LBYL](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl), because otherwise there are huge openings for race conditions. Just `try` the `makedirs`, and handle the `EEXIST` by doing nothing (or, if you prefer, you can even `try` the `open`, and handle the `ENOENT` by trying `makedirs`…).

Comment: If you are really looking for a temporary file, [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) might be more appropriate.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Definitely… but if you want a specific directory instead of the default (e.g., you need to guarantee a directory with no spaces in it), `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` (and `mkstemp` and so on) doesn't create directories either, so he could have the same problem anyway.

Comment: By the way, an even better solution is to update to a more modern Python. In 3.2, you can just call `os.makedirs(dir, exist_ok=True)`. In 3.1, you can at least catch `FileExistsError` instead of catching `OSError` and checking the `errno`.

Comment: @abarnert Using EAFP rather than LBYL changes nothing regarding race conditions. There's a race no matter what between the call to `makedirs` and that to `open`. And there's always a race inside `makedirs`. I agree that testing for existence is crappy. But so is catching the exception. Python 3.2 and `exist_ok` is the right approach, but question says 2.7.

Comment: Using `dir` as a variable name is not ideal - this has the side effect of overwriting the `dir()` builtin.

Answer (score 3):

If you try to create a file in a directory that doesn't exist, you will get that error.

You need to ensure the directory exists first. You can do that with `os.makedirs()` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could check if the file exists before opening it with:

`os.path.exists (afile)`

Which will either say True or False, depending on whether it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same kind of error while scraping a website, as I was trying to create a text file named from the scraped title, because the scraped data contained special characters like `/?:"|<>`. But my OS doesn't let me create a file name with those special characters.

If that's the case, you can use Regex to replace those characters with an empty string.

Here is the code:

```
import re
test_str = "a/b?c<d>e|f"
new_str = re.sub(r"[\*\/:?\"<>|]", "", test_str, re.MULTILINE)
# new_str == abcdef
```