# Python 3, getting file not found error on absolute path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a binary file i'm downloading from The Movie Database. I can successfully save the file if it's on the same folder the .py file is, but cannot save it on a location outside it even after the containing directory is created by the script and using absolute path:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/gabriel/Desktop/movies/w185/tt2024544.jpeg'
```

Pice of code:

```
filepath    =   os.path.join(webDir,size,imdbid + '.' + filetype);
f           =   open(filepath, "wb");
```

I'm puzzled. Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: What code is causing that exception? My best guest is that you're not opening the file for writing....

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include that, as well as how `filepath` is assigned?

Comment: Dang, did not see the edit file, correcting...

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? Are you sure all subfolders, i.e. movies and w185 already exist? Linux is case-sensitive so check to ensure you are using the correct casing.

Comment: @Gabriel do all subdirectories exist? You need to ensure that /home/gabriel/Desktop/movies/w185/` exists...

Comment: Yes indeed. As i stated, the directory is even created by my script if does not exist.

Comment: How are you creating the directory? Also - for a sanity check... you're sure the directory does exist? (ie, you can cd into it inside a shell...and maybe check that something like `echo test > somefilename` works as the same user the Python process will be running as?)

Comment: Oh, i'm at work and dont have access to the code, but yes, the directory exists and i can access it via CLI or Nautilus. I will check permissions tho.

Comment: The directories are accessed by CLI and the permissions are right (drwxr-xr-x). Even executing the script as root throws the same error.

Comment: If it only works fine if they're in the same folder, you might be saving relative to the current directory. Also the `os.path.join` docs say "If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components will be discarded." Make sure none of the arguments have a slash in front of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use open(filename, 'w' ) gives IOError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory if directory doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758673/trying-to-use-openfilename-w-gives-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-dire)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it turned out that a directory in my **absolute path was not existing**. One can easily check with:

```
import os
path = os.path.split(filepath)[0]
print('check for path', os.path.exists(path))
```