# Python - working with .csv-files

Tags: python, file, csv, numpy

I have a .csv file with a lot of data in it. 
I tried to open it with:

```
import csv

filename = raw_input('Your filename: ')
with open(filename,'r') as myFile:
  dataFromFile = csv.reader(myFile)
  print dataFromFile
```

As far as I know `csv.reader` converts the data from the file into a list.

I wanted to open the file 
`2015-09-02_17:59:43.csv` But I get the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2015-09-02_17:59:43.csv '
```

Ok, I googled it and found the following question on stack overflow: [Trying to use open( filename, 'w' ) gives IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758673/trying-to-use-open-filename-w-gives-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-dir)
So I tried the solution from there. 
But then I got another error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

Then I renamed my file to timestamp.csv because I was curious if the name might be an issus and tried my first solution. 
So suddenly the file could be found but as a print output I got the following: 
`<_csv.reader object at 0x104c88a60>`. I thought if I printed `dataFromFile` out it would show me the entire list.

So first question here: Does this `<_csv.reader object at 0x104c88a60>`mean that the list is to long to be displayed so it just tells me what object I have ?

Second question: Why didn't my previous attempts to solve work?

And I found a little workaround with:

```
for currentRow in dataFromFile:
 print currentRow
```

So row after row is printed out. But not exactly what I wanted.

Last but not least I want to transform my list into a **numpy array** what would be the easiest way ?

**EDIT**
I already found an answer and way for my last question, it is pretty easy I guess:

```
 import numpy as np
 np.array(dataFromFile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I know csv.reader converts the data from the file into a
>   list.

This is the mistaken assumption.

From the Python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), csv.reader:

> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile.

It is an iterator, not a list. Thus, you get a csv.reader object. If you did

```
list(dataFromFile)
```

it would display what you're expecting.

EDIT: Addressing your edit, I think you're looking for something like from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-to-read-csv-into-record-array-in-numpy). Essentially, `genfromtxt()` in numpy does what you're trying to do with converting a CSV to numpy array.

P.S. In general, you should probably ask another question if the topic is completely different--keeps it cleaner and makes your question less of a moving target

Comment: thanks for your help. do you also know why my first attempts didn't work ?

Comment: @Sascha There is an extra space after the `.csv` in your error code. You inputted the wrong file name.

Answer (score 1):

the csv.reader function doesn't return a list, it returns an iterator object wich you can use to get line by line. If you want to get a list of lines just do it like this:

```
#get list of lines
lines = open("your file").readlines()
#if you want to get the list with the values of each line separated by ',' you can do it like this:
lines2 = [line.split(',') for line in open("your file").readlines()]
```