# Write a file to a directory that doesn't exist

Tags: python, directory

How do I using `with open() as f: ...` to write the file in a directory that doesn't exist.

For example:

```py
with open('/Users/bill/output/output-text.txt', 'w') as file_to_write:
    file_to_write.write("{}\n".format(result))
```

Let's say the `/Users/bill/output/` directory doesn't exist.  If the directory doesn't exist just create the directory and write the file there.

Comment: I've been using [this snippet](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/82465-a-friendly-mkdir/) for years and years.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to first create the directory.

The `mkdir -p` implementation [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python) will do just what you want. `mkdir -p` will create any parent directories as required, and silently do nothing if it already exists.

Here I've implemented a `safe_open_w()` method which calls `mkdir_p` on the directory part of the path, before opening the file for writing:

```
import os, os.path
import errno

# Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/600612/119527
def mkdir_p(path):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
    except OSError as exc: # Python >2.5
        if exc.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(path):
            pass
        else: raise

def safe_open_w(path):
    ''' Open "path" for writing, creating any parent directories as needed.
    '''
    mkdir_p(os.path.dirname(path))
    return open(path, 'w')

with safe_open_w('/Users/bill/output/output-text.txt') as f:
    f.write(...)
```

Updated for Python 3:

```
import os, os.path

def safe_open_w(path):
    ''' Open "path" for writing, creating any parent directories as needed.
    '''
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path), exist_ok=True)
    return open(path, 'w')

with safe_open_w('/Users/bill/output/output-text.txt') as f:
    f.write(...)
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Just for clarification, the `mkdir_p` function  used in your code has to be defined as well, using the link provided. It does not come with Python.

Comment: @HuuNguyen Added that clarification, thanks. Still not sure why someone downvoted this.

Comment: For `exc.errno == errno.EEXIST` I got the error:

`NameError: global name 'errno' is not defined`.

Changing it to `exc.errno == 17` worked.

Comment: @Jacob You need to `import errno`.

Comment: Nowadays, you can avoid the error handling by passing `exists_ok=True` to `os.makedirs`

Comment: `exist_ok` (no `s` on the end of `exist`)

Answer (score 44):

Using [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) (in Python 3.5 and up, to support the `exist_ok` parameter):

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('Users') / 'bill' / 'output'
p.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
with (p / 'output-text.txt').open('w') as opened_file:
    opened_file.write(...)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2020. There is no need to mess with custom functions and the os module anymore.

Comment: Note you may want to specify `parents=True` to get the expected behavior of creating all directories that don't exist for the file.

Answer (score 17):

Make liberal use of the `os` module:

```
import os

if not os.path.isdir('/Users/bill/output'):
    os.mkdir('/Users/bill/output')

with open('/Users/bill/output/output-text.txt', 'w') as file_to_write:
    file_to_write.write("{}\n".format(result))
```

Comment: This doesn't handle making the intermediate directories as well.

Comment: Of course not, and this is a complete assumption on my part. I think `/Users/bill` exists though.

Answer (score 13):

The [answer given by Yakir Tsuberi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56925053/4298200) is great but I would like to add that you need the parameter `parents=True` for nested folders as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory). Thus, the code would look as follows:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('Users/bill/output')
p.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
with (p / 'output-text.txt').open('w') as opened_file:
    opened_file.write(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just *create* the path you want to create the file using **os.makedirs**:

```
import os
import errno

def make_dir(path):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)  # Python>3.2
    except TypeError:
        try:
            os.makedirs(path)
        except OSError as exc: # Python >2.5
            if exc.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(path):
                pass
            else: raise
```

Source: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python/600612#600612)  SO solution