# python nested for loops requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have two lists. One has the urls and the other the filenames. The filename should change with the for loop for each video.  I get the following error:

```
open(f'{k[1:]}.mp4', 'wb').write(r.content) ,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '10560.mp4'
```

```
def download_cdn():

    links = get_cdn_link()
    file_name = get_link()

    for i in links:
        for k in file_name:
            r = requests.get(i, allow_redirects=True)
            open(f'{k[1:]}.mp4', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

```
file_name = ['/yxz/10560', '/yxz/10561', '/yxz/10562', '/yxz/10578', '/asd/10565', '/asd/10564']
```

Comment: Do the directories `yxz` and `asd` already exist in the directory where the code is being executed?

Comment: no but I cut the first string to remove the "/" with [1:]

Comment: When writing to a file path if the directory does not already exists, [you need to create the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793987/write-file-to-a-directory-that-doesnt-exist)

Comment: `[1:]` only removes the first character here, so because there's a second slash it treats what comes before it as a directory.

Comment: in concert with @DarrylG question, does the directories "yxz" and "asd" already exist?

Comment: Thanks now it works. I removed both slashes

Answer (score -1):

Place `{k[1:]}` outside of the quotes. Python is treating it as a literal string instead of a variable. Do this instead:

`open(str(k[1:]) + '.mp4', 'wb').write(r.content)`

or use `.format()`

`open('{}.mp4'.format(k[1:]), 'wb').write(r.content)`

Comment: @KAN What does your filename list look like? Could you add that to your original post please?

Comment: "Place {k[1:]} outside of the quotes. Python is treating it as a literal string instead of a variable." This is not correct, it's currently formatted as an f-string. Code inside of braces is executed in f-strings.

Comment: I have added the list in original post

Comment: Oops didn't noticed the `f` my bad.