# Creating a directory based on function parameters, Python

Tags: python, function, directory, creation

Suppose I have a function:

```
def function(a,b,c):
    do some stuff
    array = some calcualated values
    np.savetxt('/home/user/'+str(a)+'<z<'+str(b)+'/mass/M_'+str(c)+'.dat',array)
```

As you can see I am saving a file called `M_+str(c)+.dat` in the path `/home/user/'+str(a)+'<z<'+str(b)+'/mass/`.

The problem I have is that, ***both `str(a)+'<z<'+str(b)` and `mass` folders don't exist.***

I have to create them inside the function and save the file inside these folders. How do I achieve this task?

Comment: Have you even *tried* to make those directories? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: to be frank, I don't know how to do it!! When I just run the function with `a,b,c` parameters, I get the obvious error `No such file or directory`.

Comment: And you aren't off Googling *"python create directory"* because...?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I did, but I don't find any solutions for my specific case. I can use `os.mkdir`, but how do I do it when I need the directory names to be based on my function paramters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python

Comment: Given that `mkdir` just takes a string, the name of the directory, which you're *already creating in your function*, what's the problem?! *"I don't find any solutions for my specific case"* - so you take the general solution and adapt it to your specific case (or *"do programming"*, as it's known).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: So before I save the file, I should call `os.mkdir(path name with function params)` and then save it, right?

Comment: Why don't you try that, and find out? The worst that can happen is that you get a different error message, and then you just try to solve that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: actually yes, I shall give that a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the directory with :

```
os.mkdir
```

See the doc : https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html