# Python - Create multiple folders by reading csv file and also check if folders already exists, if not make a new folder

Tags: python, csv

I want to first read csv file then check if the folders exists, if not create a new one.
I have information from csv file as follows:

[image]

After reading csv file it should create program folder then under program folder it game type sub folder then developer sub folder and game char sub folder. The folder structure should look something like this:

> 1. A380 / Warcraft / 69 / Blizzard / Strategy
> 2. A380 / Overwatch/ 69 / Blizzard / Shooter
> 3. A350 / Skyrim / 51 / Bethesda / Role Playing

So there will be multiple folders inside for example warcraft and overwatch will be two folders inside A380 folder.

So far I have done this:

```html
import os
import csv

output_root = r'/myProgram'

#csv_filename = raw_input('Enter CSV filename:')
with open('insurance_sample.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
    header = next(readCSV)
```

Please let me know if the question is still confusing and I will try to explain in more detail.

Comment: So you wrote some code.  Does it work?  Why or why not?

Comment: Are you on windows or linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to extract the values of one row and join them to a path name. Afterwards `os.path.exists` checks if the directory exists and `os.makedirs` creates recursively the directories for you.

So you can try this:

```
import os
import csv

with open('insurance_sample.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
    header = readCSV.next()
    for row in readCSV:
        dirname = "/".join((row[0], row[1], row[3], row[4], row[7]))
        if not os.path.exists(dirname):
            os.makedirs(dirname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probable dupe of [mkdir -p functionality in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python) but it's not clear to me how this poster would find this without knowing about mkdir -p.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that following code may help you:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = "/home/sansingh/sanDocs/programs/sample.csv"

data = pd.read_csv(path)
for i in range(len(data)):
    row = data.iloc[i]
    program = row["Program"]
    gametype = row["Game Type"]
    dev = row["Developer"]
    gamechar = row["Game Char"]
    if(os.path.exists(program) == False):
        os.makedir(program)
        os.makedir(program + "/" + gametype)
        os.makedir(program + "/" + gametype + "/" + dev)
        os.makedir(program + "/" + gametype + "/" + dev + "/" + gamechar)
    else:
        if(os.path.exists(program + "/" + gametype) == False):
            os.makedir(program + "/" + gametype)
            os.makedir(program + "/" + gametype + "/" + dev)
            os.makedir(program + "/" + gametype + "/" + dev + "/" + gamechar)
        else:
            if(os.path.exists(program + "/" + gametype + "/" + dev) == False):
                os.makedir(program + "/" + gametype + "/" + dev)
                os.makedir(program + "/" + gametype + "/" + dev + "/" + gamechar)
            else:
                if(os.path.exists(program + "/" + gametype + "/" + dev + "/" + gamechar) == False):
                    os.makedir(program + "/" + gametype + "/" + dev + "/" + gamechar)
```

I haven't tested my code but I hope that this may helps you..

Comment: Too much code bro. Bash's "mkdir -p ./../.." does the checking and making.