# I don't get why my python file creation is not working

Tags: python, createfile

```
import sys

filepath = "D:\\Desktop\\SIGN IN OUT\\"
times = ["min.txt","hour.txt","datein.txt","dateout.txt"]

while True:
    z = input("Enter Your First and Last Name. Just don't put a . in your name. : ")
    y = z+'\\'+z
    for x in range(len(times)):
        f = open(filepath+y+times[x],'w')
        f.write('0')
        f.close()
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors? What exactly is making file creation 'not work'?

Answer (score 3):

Joining files with `\\` is not the best way to do it. The recommended way is using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) from the `os` module:

```
import os

while True:
    z = input("Enter Your First and Last Name. Just don't put a . in your name. : ")
    y = os.path.join(*z.split())
    for x in times:
        with open(os.path.join(filepath, y, x), 'w') as f:
            f.write('0')
```

I also recommend -

1. Using a context manager to handle your files, it makes your code cleaner.
2. Iterating over `times` directly rather than the indices

---

Also, as Jean-François Fabre states in his answer, you'd better use `os.mkdir` to create any directories that don't exist before you create files in them. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/600612/4909087) a good reference.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning the choice of doing `for x in times:` instead of the range, as well?

Comment: Can you please add `import os` to the top of your code?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that doesn't fix OP's error like _at all_. It's rather a "code review" answer. The issue is still there because `y` path part doesn't exist, since the user just entered it

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Good point. I would up vote your answer but I've Voxxed myself. Anyway, I've mentioned it as a footnote. Won't duplicate because you've already said it :)

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that in that code:

```
z = input("Enter Your First and Last Name. Just don't put a . in your name. : ")
y = z+'\\'+z
```

- `y` is two times the same value, joined by `\\` (won't give you the directories you're expecting, but that's not the main issue)
- but when trying to open your file, you're doing that in a directory that probably *doesn't exist*.

So you'll have to add (using `os.path.join` is cleaner as @COLDSPEED noted):

```
my_dir = os.path.join(filepath, y)
if not os.path.isdir(my_dir):
    os.makedirs(my_dir)  # creates dirs if doesn't exist, with full path
```

before opening your files so the directory supposed to contain them exists (`open` fails if the directory doesn't exist)