# How to rename/replace a particular keyword with unicode character for all files and the associated folders?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, glob, python-os

I have the following files and subdirectories in a directory (`'input_folder'`) and I would like to change the name of all the files with `'.dat'` extension and all the folders that have a particular keyword (e.g., `ABC`) with a Unicode character. A MWE is given below:

```
import os
import random
import errno    
#--------------------------------------
# Create random folders and files

# tzot's forced directory create hack https://stackoverflow.com/a/600612/4576447
def mkdir_p(path):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
    except OSError as exc:  # Python >2.5
        if exc.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(path):
            pass
        else:
            raise


if not os.path.isdir('./input_folder'):
    os.makedirs('input_folder')
for i in range(10):
    mkdir_p('./input_folder/folder_ABC_' + str(random.randint(100,999)))


for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./input_folder'):
    for dir in dirs:
        result = open(os.path.join(root,dir) + '/ABC ' + str(random.randint(100,999)) + '.dat','w')
        result = open(os.path.join(root,dir) + '/XYZ-ABC ' + str(random.randint(100,999)) + '.dat','w')

#--------------------------------------
# Main rename code

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./input_folder'):
    for file in files:  
        if file.endswith((".dat")):
            os.rename(file, file.replace('ABC', u'\u2714'.encode('utf-8')))
```

This MWE gives the following error:

```
os.rename(file, file.replace('ABC', u'\u2714'.encode('utf-8')))
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

How to correctly rename all the files and folders that has ABC with a unioode character in Python 2.7?

Comment: One likely problem is in the renaming loop at the end, you need to do something like `file = os.path.join(root, file)` to get the complete path to the file being renamed by the `os.rename()` call. In addition it's also possible your OS doesn't allow that Unicode character in file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least five issues:

1. When dealing with Unicode, use it everywhere.  `os.walk` will return Unicode filenames if passed a Unicode path.  `from __future__ import unicode_literals` will default strings to Unicode.
2. When opening files, close them.  You'll run into problems later when renaming.  `result` still exists and has a reference to the last file opened.
3. As mentioned in a comment, use `os.path.join` on the `root` and the `file` for both the before and after name.
4. Use `os.walk` with `topdown=False`.  This will process the leaf nodes first, so the directory tree isn't corrupted (and keeping `root` and `dirs` valid) while traversing it.
5. Rename the files first, then the directories, again to not corrupt the directory tree while traversing it.

Result:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

# Skipping unchanged code...

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./input_folder'):
    for dir in dirs:
        # One way to ensure the file is closed.
        with open(os.path.join(root,dir) + '/ABC ' + str(random.randint(100,999)) + '.dat','w'):
            pass
        with open(os.path.join(root,dir) + '/XYZ-ABC ' + str(random.randint(100,999)) + '.dat','w'):
            pass

#--------------------------------------
# Main rename code

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./input_folder',topdown=False):
    for file in files:  
        if file.endswith((".dat")):
            # Generate the full file path names.
            filename1 = os.path.join(root,file)
            filename2 = os.path.join(root,file.replace('ABC', '\u2714'))
            os.rename(filename1,filename2)
    for d in dirs:  
        # Generate the full directory path names.
        dirname1 = os.path.join(root,d)
        dirname2 = os.path.join(root,d.replace('ABC', '\u2714'))
        os.rename(dirname1,dirname2)
```

Comment: This does not rename the folder, if you could edit the code to rename the folders, I could accept the answer.

Comment: @Tom Updated.  As written it works in Python 2 and 3 as well.