# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] when using two concatenated strings

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having troubles creating directories when concatenating one or more strings as part of the filename. As an example:

```
DIR = r"D:/My/Directory"
classes = ['itemA', 'itemB']


for item in classes:
    for scope in ["training/", "testing/"]:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(DIR, scope + item))
```

Creates the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path
>   specified:
>   'D:/My/Directory\\training/itemA'

The `os.mkdir` works when I'm not using `scope + item`, but when I do it throws this error. I'm not sure how the function handles `training/itemA` differently than `trainingitemA` when they are both interpreted as a string literal.

Comment: Are you on windows and using forward slashes (`/`)? Shouldn't they be backwards? I'm not using windows but this seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path separator on Windows is `\` and not `/`, also you can use `os.path.join` again to join the `scope` to the `item`:

```py
DIR = r"D:\My\Directory"
classes = ['itemA', 'itemB']


for item in classes:
    for scope in ["training", "testing"]:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(DIR, scope, item))
```

Also make sure that the parent directories (e.g. `D:\My\Directory\training`) exist before trying to create subdirectories, or use `os.mkdirs` instead of `os.mkdir` (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python)).

Comment: Thank You! Worked like a charm! Just for clarification: is there a better way than to use `os.mkdir(os.path.join(DIR, 'train'))` for both train and test, and then having to loop?

Comment: You mean for creating the parent and the child? Yes, you can use `os.mkdirs`: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-makedirs-method/