# How do I check if a directory exists in Python?

Tags: python, directory

How do I check if a directory exists in Python?

Comment: A word of warning - the highest rated answer might be susceptible to race conditions. You might want to perform `os.stat` instead, to see if the directory both exists and is a directory at the same moment.

Comment: @d33tah You may have a good point but I don't see a way to use `os.stat` to tell directory from a file. It raises `OSError` when the path is invalid, no matter whether it's file or directory. Also, any code after checking is also susceptible to race conditions.

Answer (score 2324, accepted):

Use [**`os.path.isdir`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) for directories only:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isdir('new_folder')
True
```

Use [**`os.path.exists`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) for both files and directories:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'new_folder', 'file.txt'))
False
```

Alternatively, you can use [**`pathlib`**](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/pathlib.html):

```
 >>> from pathlib import Path
 >>> Path('new_folder').is_dir()
 True
 >>> (Path.cwd() / 'new_folder' / 'file.txt').exists()
 False
```

Comment: @syedrakib While parentheses can be used to indicate that an object is callable, that's not useful in Python, since even classes are callable. Also, functions are first-class values in Python, and you can use them *without* the parentheses notation, like in `existing = filter(os.path.isdir(['/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/local/lib'])`

Comment: You can pass functions to other functions, like `map`, but in the general case, you call functions with arguments and parentheses. Also, there is some typo in your example. presumably you mean `filter(os.path.isdir, ['/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/local/lib'])`.

Comment: Also, there is `os.path.isfile(path)` if you only care about whether it is a file.

Comment: Be aware that on some platforms these will return false if the file/directory exists, but a read permission error also occurs.

Comment: The examples above are not portable, and would be better if rewritten using os.path.join, or the pathlib stuff recommended below.  Something like this:
print(os.path.isdir(os.path.join('home', 'el')))

Comment: @user2773661 Good point. I updated the examples. Note your sample is **not** identical because an absolute path must start with a slash; I answered the original question. I left out explaining the difference between starting with `.` vs `os.getcwd()`, since it is irrelevant for most application.

Comment: For the `pathlib` option (which I prefer), you can also just use the relative path like `(Path.('new_folder') / 'file.txt').exists()`. To resolve the path to a full qualified (absolute) path, you can use `Path(...).resolve()`

Comment: Using isdir or exists only works once, after that it returns true even if the folder is not there.

Comment: @SAPASFlash That would be a very major bug in Python or your operating system, which you should file or ask a separate question. It's much more likely there is a bug in your program you use to detect it. Ideally, write a little program (as small as possible – should only be 3 lines) to reproduce it and submit it to the Python bugtracker, along with a lot of information about your system, and whether the problem occurs on other computers (e.g. on which of Linux, Mac, or Windows).

Comment: @phihag yes, i think I will have to do that. Recently, I made a PIL based visiting card maker for a friend and when I was configuring the folders with validations, I got to see this. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 126):

Python 3.4 introduced [the `pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#) into the standard library, which provides an object oriented approach to handle filesystem paths. The `is_dir()` and `exists()` methods of a `Path` object can be used to answer the question:

```
In [1]: from pathlib import Path

In [2]: p = Path('/usr')

In [3]: p.exists()
Out[3]: True

In [4]: p.is_dir()
Out[4]: True
```

Paths (and strings) can be joined together with the `/` operator:

```
In [5]: q = p / 'bin' / 'vim'

In [6]: q
Out[6]: PosixPath('/usr/bin/vim') 

In [7]: q.exists()
Out[7]: True

In [8]: q.is_dir()
Out[8]: False
```

Pathlib is also available on Python 2.7 via [the pathlib2 module on PyPi.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/)

Answer (score 95):

So close! `os.path.isdir` returns `True` if you pass in the name of a directory that currently exists. If it doesn't exist or it's not a directory, then it returns `False`.

Comment: and if you want to create it `os.path.isdir(path) or os.makedirs(path)`

Comment: Or using pathlib: `Path(path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)` creates a nested path in one operation.

Answer (score 55):

Yes, use [`os.path.exists()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists).

Comment: That doesn't check that the path is a directory.

Comment: Good call. Others have pointed out that `os.path.isdir` will accomplish that.

Comment: If you understand that this doesn't answer the question, why don't you remove the answer?

Comment: @CamilStaps This question was viewed 354000 times (by now). Answers here are not only for OP, they are for anyone who could come here for whatever reason. aganders3's answer is pertinent even if it does not directly resolve OP's problem.

Comment: @Gabriel then it should be made clear in the answer what this actually does.

Comment: To be fair, the statement “find if a directory exists” tends to exclude the non-directory case by implication: we have a “notional directory” that either exists or doesn’t.  That doesn’t make this a particularly *useful* way of thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 25):

We can check with 2 built in functions

```
os.path.isdir("directory")
```

It will give boolean true the specified directory is available.

```
os.path.exists("directoryorfile")
```

It will give boolead true if specified directory or file is available.

To check whether the path is directory;

`os.path.isdir("directorypath")`

will give boolean true if the path is directory

Comment: This is entirely redundant with the older, top answer.

Answer (score 23):

The following code checks the referred directory in your code exists or not, if it doesn't exist in your workplace then, it creates one:

```
import os

if not os.path.isdir("directory_name"):
    os.mkdir("directory_name")
```

Comment: pathlib.Path returns 'D:\\blah\\blah'. but this format is not recognisable by os.path. is there a way to solve?

Answer (score 19):

Yes use [os.path.isdir(path)](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir)

Answer (score 17):

#### You may also want to create the directory if it's not there.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory/273227#273227), if it's still there on SO.

=====================================================================

On Python ≥ 3.5, use [`pathlib.Path.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir):

```
from pathlib import Path
Path("/my/directory").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

For older versions of Python, I see two answers with good qualities, each with a small flaw, so I will give my take on it:

Try [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists), and consider [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) for the creation.

```
import os
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
```

As noted in comments and elsewhere, there's a race condition – if the directory is created between the `os.path.exists` and the `os.makedirs` calls, the `os.makedirs` will fail with an `OSError`. Unfortunately, blanket-catching `OSError` and continuing is not foolproof, as it will ignore a failure to create the directory due to other factors, such as insufficient permissions, full disk, etc.

One option would be to trap the `OSError` and examine the embedded error code (see [Is there a cross-platform way of getting information from Python’s OSError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273698/is-there-a-cross-platform-way-of-getting-information-from-pythons-oserror)):

```
import os, errno

try:
    os.makedirs(directory)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
```

Alternatively, there could be a second `os.path.exists`, but suppose another created the directory after the first check, then removed it before the second one – we could still be fooled.

Depending on the application, the danger of concurrent operations may be more or less than the danger posed by other factors such as file permissions. The developer would have to know more about the particular application being developed and its expected environment before choosing an implementation.

Modern versions of Python improve this code quite a bit, both by exposing [`FileExistsError`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/exceptions.html?#FileExistsError) (in 3.3+)...

```
try:
    os.makedirs("path/to/directory")
except FileExistsError:
    # directory already exists
    pass
```

...and by allowing [a keyword argument to `os.makedirs` called `exist_ok`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) (in 3.2+).

```
os.makedirs("path/to/directory", exist_ok=True)  # succeeds even if directory exists.
```

Answer (score 14):

As in:

```
In [3]: os.path.exists('/d/temp')
Out[3]: True
```

Probably toss in a `os.path.isdir(...)` to be sure.

Answer (score 13):

Just to provide the `os.stat` version (python 2):

```
import os, stat, errno
def CheckIsDir(directory):
  try:
    return stat.S_ISDIR(os.stat(directory).st_mode)
  except OSError, e:
    if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
      return False
    raise
```

Comment: What is the advantage to use `stat` and `errno` instead of [pathlib2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/)? Is it the race conditions mentioned in [d33tah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1091116/d33tah)'s comment to the question?

Answer (score 10):

os provides you with a lot of these capabilities:

```
import os
os.path.isdir(dir_in) #True/False: check if this is a directory
os.listdir(dir_in)    #gets you a list of all files and directories under dir_in
```

the listdir will throw an exception if the input path is invalid.

Answer (score 9):

```
#You can also check it get help for you

if not os.path.isdir('mydir'):
    print('new directry has been created')
    os.system('mkdir mydir')
```

Comment: python has builtin functions to create directories, so better use `os.makedirs('mydir')` instead of `os.system(...)`

Comment: You are printing that *'new directory has been created'* but you do not know that. What if you do not have permissions to create a directory? You would print *'new directory has been created'* but it would not be true. Would it.

Answer (score 7):

There is a convenient [`Unipath`](https://github.com/mikeorr/Unipath) module.

```
>>> from unipath import Path 
>>>  
>>> Path('/var/log').exists()
True
>>> Path('/var/log').isdir()
True
```

Other related things you might need:

```
>>> Path('/var/log/system.log').parent
Path('/var/log')
>>> Path('/var/log/system.log').ancestor(2)
Path('/var')
>>> Path('/var/log/system.log').listdir()
[Path('/var/foo'), Path('/var/bar')]
>>> (Path('/var/log') + '/system.log').isfile()
True
```

You can install it using pip:

```
$ pip3 install unipath
```

It's similar to the built-in `pathlib`. The difference is that it treats every path as a string (`Path` is a subclass of the `str`), so if some function expects a string, you can easily pass it a `Path` object without a need to convert it to a string.

For example, this works great with Django and `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(2)
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/tmp/static'
```

Answer (score 6):

Step 1: Import the os.path module 
import the os.path module before running the code.

```
import os.path
from os import path
```

Step 2: Use path.exists() function 
The path.exists() method is used to find whether a file exists.

```
path.exists("your_file.txt")
```

Step 3: Use os.path.isfile() 
We can use the isfile command to determine whether or not a given input is a file.

```
path.isfile('your_file.txt')
```

step 4: Use os.path.isdir() 
We can use the os.path.dir() function to determine whether or not a given input is a directory.

```
path.isdir('myDirectory')
```

Here is the complete code

```
    import os.path
    from os import path
    
    def main():
    
       print ("File exists:"+str(path.exists('your_file.txt')))
       print ("Directory exists:" + str(path.exists('myDirectory')))
       print("Item is a file: " + str(path.isfile("your_file.txt")))
       print("Item is a directory: " + str(path.isdir("myDirectory")))
    
    if __name__== "__main__":
       main()
```

**pathlibPath.exists() For Python 3.4**

Pathlib Module is included in Python 3.4 and later versions to handle file system paths. Python checks if a folder exists using an object-oriented technique.

```
import pathlib
file = pathlib.Path("your_file.txt")
if file.exists ():
    print ("File exist")
else:
    print ("File not exist")
```

- os.path.exists() – Returns True if path or directory does exists.
- os.path.isfile() – Returns True if path is File.
- os.path.isdir() – Returns True if path is Directory.
- pathlib.Path.exists() – Returns True if path or directory does exists. (In Python 3.4 and above versions)

Article refered [How do I check if directory exists in Python?](https://shortbuzz.in/blog/shortbuzz.in/python-check-if-directory-exists-how-to-check-if-a-file-exists)

Answer (score 5):

Two things

1. check if the directory exist?
2. if not, create a directory (optional).

```
import os
dirpath = "<dirpath>" # Replace the "<dirpath>" with actual directory path.

if os.path.exists(dirpath):
   print("Directory exist")
else: #this is optional if you want to create a directory if doesn't exist.
   os.mkdir(dirpath):
   print("Directory created")
```

Comment: If you're going to do this then why not just os.mkdir() and catch (and ignore) FileExistsError. Your example has a time-of-check/time-of-use race. There is a non-zero delay between checking that dirpath exists and then taking action if it doesn't. In that time someone else could potentially make an object at dirpath and you'd have to deal with the exception anyway.

Comment: @AdamHawes, the solution is based on the query that was asked, the query specifically ask about "find if a directory exists", once the ` if os.path.exists ` is validated, it is up to the coder to decide on further proceedings, ` os.mkdir ` is only an assumptive action, hence I mentioned it as an option in the code.