# Using Python to create incrementing folder names

Tags: python

I am trying to place all files within a directory into it's own individual folder.  When trying to declare the variable 'folders' I enumerate the list of files and try to append the enumerated list number to the end of the folder name, so the folders would look something like...
    FOLDER_1,
    FOLDER_2,
    FOLDER_3,
where the trailing digit is generated from enumeration of the files in the directory.

However my code below lists them all as 'FOLDER_0' and then hits an overwrite error, my increment doesn't seem to be working, any direction into what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

```
PATH = "C:/Temp/"

def main(): 
    files = [ join(PATH, f) for f in listdir(PATH) if isfile(join(PATH, f)) ]

    for i, f in enumerate (files):
        folders = [ PATH+"FOLDER_"+str(i)+"/" for f in files ]
```

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: What does `files` look like after your list comprehension?

Comment: What would you like to have in `folders` after the for-loop? Now you iterate through files but use `f` nowhere, i.e. the last line is equivalent to folders = [ PATH+"FOLDER_"+str(i)+"/" ] * len(files), which may not be what you want. Also, you are using the variable `f` twice (outer and inner loop), which really may cause problems.

Comment: Each time you perform the `for` cycle, a new variable `folders` is created. You must initialize an empty variable `folders = []` before the `for` cycle and then use the `list.append()` method or the `+=` operator to add a new item: `folders.append([ PATH+"FOLDER_"+str(i)+"/" for f in files ])`

Comment: However, I see more discrepancies. Why do you use `enumerate` if you do not need it? You can also use: `for i in range(len(files))` or make a one-line function as for the `files` variable: `folders = [ PATH+"FOLDER_"+str(i)+"/" for i in range(len(files)) ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really clear what your end goal is, but from what you have shown in your code and written in your question I think I can take a stab at it.

- To start python uses zero based indexing, so the first value corresponding to the first item in `enumerate` will be `0`.
- Next your `for` loop is equivalent to doing something like this:

`folders = [PATH + "FOLDER_" + str(len(files))] * len(files)`

So for...

`files=["file1", "file2"]`

you would get...

`folders=["FOLDER_1", "FOLDER_1"]`

- This is likely where the "overwrite error" is indirectly coming form.  If you tried to create every folder in `folders` you get an `OSError` telling you that you are creating a folder you just created.

If you wanted to create a folder for each file you had in a directory, I would try to modify your code into this direction:

```
PATH = "C:/Temp/"

def main():
    files = [join(PATH, f) for f in listdir(PATH) if isfile(join(PATH, f))]
    folders = [join(PATH, "FOLDER_{}".format(i + 1)) for i, _ in enumerate(files)]
    ...
```

And then if you are going to create all the folders in `folders` check they don't already [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933237/how-to-find-if-directory-exists-in-python)

Comment: Thank you so much MrAlias, your solution is exactly what I was looking for, and much more efficient than my original method.  Cheers!