# Python find out if a folder exists

Tags: python, os.path

I am trying to find out if a folder exists but for some reason cannot.
I am generating a string, and use `os.path.isdir` to find out if a folder with that string`s name already exists. The thing is - I get 'False' regardless.

```
import os

my_Folder_Name = 'some_string' #This is a string that I generate
print(os.path.isdir("\\" + my_Folder_Name)) #Even if this folder exists - I get False
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you prepend `'\\'`?

Comment: Use `os.path.join` to join path names in an OS independent way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find if directory exists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933237/how-to-find-if-directory-exists-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

```
import os

my_Folder_Name = 'some_string' #This is a string that I generate
print(os.path.isdir(my_Folder_Name))
```

remove "//". Why are you using "//"?

Answer (score 0):

Either use the relative path or the absolute one. Don't append '\' to your folder path.

```
print(os.path.isdir(my_folder_name))
```

(Sorry to digress, but variable names follow snake case convention in python. So if you can change that too, other python programmers would be happier)