# Verifying the existance of a file or folder using subprocess library in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I can check the presence of a file or folder using ***OS*** library very easily.
The following two links have described that
[directoryExistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933237/how-to-find-if-directory-exists-in-python) [fileExistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python)

I am attempting to use the ***subprocess*** library to do the same

and, I tried a couple of approaches already

1- `status = subprocess.call(['test','-e',<path>])`, which is always returning 1, no matter what I pass in path.

2- Using getstatusoutput,

> /bin/sh: 1: : Permission denied
>
> ```
> status, result = subprocess.getstatusoutput([<path>])
> print(status)
> print(result)
> ```
>
> which is working fine because status variable returns 126 if the file/folder exist and 127 when the file/folder doesn't exist. Also the result variable contains message but the "result" variable contains the message : Permission denied

But the second solution looks like a hack to me. Is their a better way, of doing this ?

Comment: "/bin/sh: 1: : Permission denied", is written by mistake in the second point.

Comment: The modern way is to use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use).

Comment: Not working with '~'. In my ubuntu platform

Comment: I need my path to be somethig like '~/workspace/datasets'.

Comment: You can use `Path.home()` to make a '~' path.

Comment: @ManishSharma. For me, your first example works fine. Are you aware that `test` returns **zero** on success and **non-zero** on failure? If you want tilde expansion, you must use e.g. `os.path.expanduser('~/workspace')`.

Comment: `~` is a shell expansion. If you want that to work in a `call()`, you'll need to add `shell=True`.

Comment: @glibdud. Using `shell=True` only works if the command is a string, rather than a list, and there are [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) to take into account.

Comment: @glibdud, it worked, it was a stupid mistake on my part, shell=True worked. Thanks

Comment: @glibdud, it worked for me, thanks for bringing in the security consideration. I am reading the username myself and generating the path separately to keep the shell=False. Is it the right way to do it ?

Comment: @ekhumoro There are certainly security considerations, but `shell=True` works fine with a list.

Comment: @glibdud Also, I noticed that the first way is not allowing me to distinguish between a file and a folder

Comment: @glibdud. No, it does not (on linux, anyway).

Comment: @glibdud, in that case I will be probably going with pathlib library.

Comment: @ManishSharma At any rate, I'm not sure why you're deciding to do it this way rather than just using `os`.

Comment: @glibdud. For me, `call(['test', '-e', '~'], shell=True)` returns `1`, but `call('test -e ~', shell=True)` returns `0`.

Comment: From Python docs:
The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes. This module intends to replace several older modules and functions:

os.system
os.spawn*

Comment: @ManishSharma That just means they're trying to replace those specific functions, not the whole module.

Comment: @glibdud, Yeah, adding shell=True works

Comment: @ManishSharma. Why are you bothering to use the shell for this? It seems totally pointless and inefficient.

Comment: Make a lot more sense to me. I should have read it carefully. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test` command is a shell builtin, and on many platforms doesn't exist as an independent command you can run.

If you use `shell=True` to use the shell to run this command, you should pass in a single string, not a list of tokens.

```
status = subprocess.call("test -e '{}'".format(path), shell=True)
```

This will produce a malformed command if `path` contains any single quotes; try `path.replace("'", r"\'")` if you want to be completely correct and robust, or use one of the existing quoting functions to properly escape any shell metacharacters in the command you pass in.

The `subprocess` library now offers a function `run()` which is slightly less unwieldy than the old legacy `call()` function; if backwards compatibility is not important, you should probably switch to that... or, as several commenters have already implored you, not use `subprocess` for this task when portable, lightweight native Python solutions are available.

Comment: For what it's worth, `test -e` merely checks whether an entry with the given name exists in the file system. Perhaps you are actually looking for `test -f` and `test -d` which additionally check whether it refers to a regular file or a directory, respectively.

Comment: Actually the `replace` hint is wrong, but too lazy to go back and fix it. Probably just use `shlex.quote(path)` and take out the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments section

```
status = subprocess.call(['test','-e',<path>])
```

can be made to work with a shell expansion if we use ***"shell=True"***

Although using os.path might be much more efficient anyways.