# Python: Check if a directory exists using os module

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, input, python-os

I'm trying to validate if a directory received as user input exists using the os module

This is how I'm accepting the input:

```
directory = input("Hi ! \n please type a directory, thanks !")
```

The idea is that I want to make sure the user will type an existing directory and nothing else

Comment: With "\" and not "\"?

Comment: os.path.isdir ?

Comment: [os.path.exists()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)

Comment: [os.path.isdir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find if directory exists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933237/how-to-find-if-directory-exists-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you read the docs for the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module?

Check out the following two links:

[os.path.exists()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)

> Return True if path refers to an existing path.

[os.path.isdir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir)

> Return True if path is an existing directory.

Answer (score 7):

```
from pathlib import Path

def is_valid_directory(filename):
    p = Path(filename)
    return p.exists() and p.is_dir()
```

`pathlib` is an enormously convenient module for working with file paths of any sort. The `p.exists()` call is redundant since `p.is_dir()` returns `False` for nonexistent paths, but checking both would allow you to e.g. give better error messages.

EDIT: Note that `pathlib` was added in Python 3.4. If you're still using an old version for whatever reason, you can use the older `os.path.isdir(filename)` function.