# How to change to a new directory that even doesn't exist?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**In python how to change to a new directory if it does exist or even doesn't exist?**

Assuming that the current working directory is '/home' (the python file is also stored there) and I wanna change it to a new directory like '/home/a'. What should I do if there are two possibilities that '/home/a' doesn't exist or does exist?

Here is my attempting code:

```
import os
current_path=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('t.py'))
print(current_path)
os.makedirs('/home/a')
os.chdir('/home/a')
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('t.py')))
```

And there is the error feedback of my code:

> [user@sahara ~]$ python t.py
>
> /home
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "t.py", line 4, in
>
> os.makedirs('/home/a')
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 221, in makedirs
>
> mkdir(name, mode)
>
> FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/home/a'

Comment: First check if the [directory exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933290/6699447). If not create it, Then switch the directory?

Comment: No need to check if you'll create it - `os.makedirs('/home/a', exist_ok=True)`

Comment: @a_python_user Exactly, that's what I wanna do

Comment: @Amadan Sorry I don't understand completely your meaning. I wanna create a new one if it doesn't exist. And it exists, just change to it.

Comment: `os.makedirs('/home/a', exist_ok=True)` will create it if it doesn't exist (and do nothing if it does). `os.chdir('/home/a')` will change to it.

Comment: @Amadan OK, I got what you mean. But my code is just like what you say, but there are some error feedbacks.

Comment: Your code is _not_ just like I say - you do not use `exist_ok` keyword parameter.

Comment: @Amadan Wow, you have solved my problems. Thank you very much!!! But one more question: After doing what you said, the python file is also stored in this new directory?

Comment: If you just made a directory, and not saved anything to it, it will be empty.

Comment: @Amadan Is there any method to save original python file in it?

Comment: Sure, `shutil.copy2(os.path.abspath(__file__), '/home/a')`.

Comment: @Amadan OK, appreciate for your help!