# Stop python program from closing when a directory is not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, directory, operating-system

Im creating a DOS clone with python and I have a command `cd` which allows you to change directory. The only problem is that if you misspell or type a non-existent directory, the program closes with a traceback error. Im basically looking for it not to completely close the program but instead `print` a statement like `'requested_directory' Is not a directory!` and allow you to type in a different directory.

Ive tried a couple things, mainly error handling, but to no prevail. Im assuming that im still not quite understanding error handling or using it incorrectly.

Any help is much appreciated.

This is the code im using to change directories (`elif` because i have many more commands. `cmd` is a raw input.)

```
elif 'cd' in cmd:
        desired_directory = cmd.split(' ')[1]
        if desired_directory == "..":
            os.chdir('..')
        else:
            os.chdir(desired_directory)
```

This is the output when an incorrect directory is typed in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jrosmac/PycharmProjects/untitled/JDOS/SYS64/jdosos.py", line 47, in <module>
    os.chdir(desired_directory)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'raw_input goes here'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find if directory exists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933237/how-to-find-if-directory-exists-in-python)

Comment: @Eric from what i have found on stack overflow, nothing explains what to do if you misspell the directory when changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to [handle](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html) the error.

```py
try:
    os.chdir(desired_directory)
except OSError as e:
    print e.args[0]
```

Comment: I should be using 3.x but im lazy and 2.7 was what i learned in the few years of school i did for programming. I might start changing the whole program over soon.

Answer (score 0):

Use exception handing:

```
try:
    os.chdir(target)
except OSError as e:
    # handle the failure of the chdir call
```