# Cannot find Python installation folder when I install Anaconda

Tags: python, path, anaconda

Hi I need to make a directory to my Python folder when trying to use a separate program that requires a python path.

[image: screenshot]

I thought Python came already installed with Anaconda3, but in my Anaconda folder there doesn't seem to a "Python" folder anywhere, like I've seen online in some other people's Anaconda install folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find if directory exists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933237/how-to-find-if-directory-exists-in-python)

Comment: no it does not I'm asking about the folder

Comment: _when trying to use a separate program_ What is the program? As an aside, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.