# How can I send a command according to two differentes directories

Tags: python, linux, paramiko

I have a python script using paramiko to get some info from a couple of servers.
My problem is that a couple of servers have a directory called **M**iddleware (capital letter), and the rest of them are **m**iddleware.

Follow the command:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("ls -d /u01/app/oracle/Middleware/OPatch")
```

The problem of this command, is that it doesn't works when the server has **m**iddleware directory.

How can I run this command to access the both directory (**M**iddleware or **m**iddleware) according to each server?

ps: I can't do this `ls -d /u01/app/oracle/*/OPatch` because there are other folders in this directory.

Tks

Comment: Use `[Mm]iddleware`.

Comment: try `client.exec_command("ls -d /u01/app/oracle/[Mm]iddleware/OPatch")` ... though really, you should avoid doing that.  I'm guessing that you really need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933290/1394729)

Comment: @jarmod [Mm]iddleware doesn't works

Comment: Did you test it first outside of Paramiko? SSH to the machine, run the command.

Comment: @jarmod I tried direct on shell script  `ssh myUser@host ls -d /u01/app/oracle/[Mm]iddleware/OPatch/` and doesnt works

Comment: Interesting. It works fine here with both Mac and with CentOS-based Linux. Did you SSH onto the host then run the command to test? Are you doubly-sure this folder exists on that host? Were there any error messages?

Comment: And ... confirmed that it also works with Paramiko, populating stdout with the full path of the Middleware folder.

Comment: In the first place, do not use shell commands to work with remote files, use SFTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution utilizing `[Mm]iddleware` works for me:

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()

def main():
    client.connect('myhostname')
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("ls -d /home/myuser/[Mm]iddleware")

    for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
        print("stdout:", line)

    for line in stderr.read().splitlines():
        print("stderr:", line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output is as follows:

```
stdout: b'/home/myuser/Middleware'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can test which one exists first

```
if [ -d /u01/app/oracle/Middleware/OPatch ];then
   stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("ls -d /u01/app/oracle/Middleware/OPatch")
elif [ -d /u01/app/oracle/middleware/OPatch ];then
   stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("ls -d /u01/app/oracle/middleware/OPatch")
fi
```

Comment: the point is that the directory is from the remote host

Comment: its pretty long but you can send it using ssh