# Automatically creating directories with file output

Tags: python, file-io

Say I want to make a file:

```
filename = "/foo/bar/baz.txt"

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write("FOOBAR")
```

This gives an `IOError`, since `/foo/bar` does not exist.

What is the most pythonic way to generate those directories automatically? Is it necessary for me explicitly call `os.path.exists` and `os.mkdir` on every single one (i.e., /foo, then /foo/bar)?

Answer (score 1008, accepted):

In Python 3.2+, using the APIs requested by the OP, you can [elegantly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) do the following:

```py
import os

filename = "/foo/bar/baz.txt"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write("FOOBAR")
```

---

With the Pathlib module (introduced in Python 3.4), there is an alternate syntax (thanks David258):

```py
from pathlib import Path
output_file = Path("/foo/bar/baz.txt")
output_file.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
output_file.write_text("FOOBAR")
```

---

In older python, there is a less elegant way:

The [`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) function does this. Try the following:

```py
import os
import errno

filename = "/foo/bar/baz.txt"
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filename)):
    try:
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename))
    except OSError as exc: # Guard against race condition
        if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write("FOOBAR")
```

The reason to add the `try-except` block is to handle the case when the directory was created between the `os.path.exists` and the `os.makedirs` calls, so that to protect us from race conditions.

---

Comment: Just had to look past `os.mkdir` and read the documentation on one more function :)

Comment: There is a slightly different approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14364249/1317713

Thoughts?

Comment: Is the inital `if not os.path.exists` needed since the `os.makedirs` uses [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)?

Comment: nice. but be aware you may need to check that the filename contains a path or attempting to create a path with an empty name (eg derived from `baz.txt`) will error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''` Obviously, this will only happen if you are writing into the present working directory.

Comment: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/foo'

Comment: @Ka-WaYip `/foo/bar/baz.txt` is just an example. Replace it with the path you wish your file to be created. In linux, the command `pwd` gives you the path to the current working directory.

Comment: with Pathlib:
`from pathlib import Path; output_file = Path("/foo/bar/baz.txt"); output_file.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True); output_file.write_text("FOOBAR")`

Comment: @David258 Sorry they closed this question so you don't get any karma for your comment that's more useful now than the actual answer. But thanks.