# FileNotFoundError while writing to a Pickle file

Tags: python, pickle

I'm taking all the filenames in a certain directory in a `list`, and would like to write this list in a `pickle` file. Here's the code I am using:

```
import _pickle as pickle
with open(filepath+'filenames.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(filenames, f)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-c59e6889d2fe> in <module>()
      1 import _pickle as pickle
----> 2 with open(dpath+'filenames.pkl', 'wb') as f:
      3     pickle.dump(filenames, f)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/train/filenames.pkl'
```

I am supposed to create this file. Why is this file expected already?

(I'm using Python 3.6.)

Comment: is the `/data/train/` present ?

Comment: yes it is present

Comment: There is a `data` folder in your root(`/`) directory which has a `train` folder in it? Please make absolutely sure that the `data` dir you are referring to is not in your project directory rather its in the `root` directory/.

Answer (score 20):

In your case most probably `/data/train/` directory does not exist

I tried this code and got same error:

```
import pickle as pickle
filenames='sadasdas'
with open('/tmp/not_exist/filenames.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(filenames, f)
```

output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6a22c2148796> in <module>()
      1 import pickle as pickle
      2 filenames='sadasdas'
----> 3 with open('/tmp/not_exist/filenames.pkl', 'wb') as f:
      4     pickle.dump(filenames, f)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/not_exist/filenames.pkl'
```

You can handle this problem by making sure the directory exists before writing to file: Programatic approach to do the same is this

```
import os
filename = "/tmp/not_exist/filenames.pkl"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
data = 'sadasdas'
with open('/tmp/not_exist/filenames.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12517490/3027854

Answer (score 7):

I also had the same problem but none of the answers helped me. 
The directories were there and I used `wb`, but again and again the same problem.

I hope this helps some who have the same issue:
I found out that the problem was that I had a lot of folders, also the name of the file was too long (due to the fact that I made up the filename as a string in which I was trying to indicate the characteristics of that file) and the folder that I was trying to dump into would raise "The file name(s) would be too long for the destination folder" when I tried to move that file manually.

After shortening the file name, the problem was resolved.

Comment: Another issue besides file length I had was the fact that in my names I had a '/' character. Could be another item to look at.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem while writing using a relative pathname (and a symlink). The directory defiantly existed but it was still raising the FileNotFoundError.

The problem disappeared when I switched to using the absolute path

```
abspath = pathlib.Path(filename).absolute()
with open(str(abspath), 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(thing_to_pickle, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to dasable 'controlled folder access' from Windows defender on Windows 10.

Other antivirus/firewall may have the same effect.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046851/windows-10-controlled-folder-access-windows-defender-security-center

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `filepath` you are using is something that *actually exists* in your computer. Sometimes we copy and paste code from somewhere else and forget to change the drive names. You may be addressing an non existing drive.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the file path already exists.
- If the path is very long, add the magic prefix `\\?\` before your path: `path = '\\\\?\\C:\\Users...`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import sys
import pickle

filenamelst = ['a.txt','b.py','c.ipynb']
filenamelst_abspathname = os.path.abspath('filenamelst.pickle')
print(filenamelst_abspathname)
picklefile = open(str(filenamelst_abspathname),'wb')
pickle.dump(filenamelst, picklefile)
picklefile.close()
```

This works. On the side of your Google Colab Notebook the pickle file will be there in the session folder. You need to download from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help anyone else, but what happened for me was that somehow the filename I was trying to save was a reserved keyword which crashed the saving. Adding another character to the name was all that was needed to allow it to pickle correctly. Here's a function you can use to flag such errors ahead of time and avoid playing whack-a-mole.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.is_reserved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).