# python: No such file or directory issue in windows 10

Tags: python

I have following code:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True, help="path to the output directory")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
jsonPath = os.path.sep.join([args["output"], "{}.json".format(os.getpid())])
f = open(jsonPath, "w")
```

I run script with arguments as '--output output'. 'output' directory is at same level as script.
I get error as:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output\xyz.json'

xyz is pid here.

What is correct way of doing it in windows 10?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517451/automatically-creating-directories-with-file-output)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. This is a Windows 10 problem, not a python problem.