# Want to create a csv inside a folder if it does not exist using string parameter in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-os

```
    dirLocation = "Patients Data/PatientsTimelineLog.csv"

try:
    if os.path.isfile(dirLocation):
        print("Directory exist." + dirLocation)
    else:
        print("Directory does not exists. Creating new one." + dirLocation)
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dirLocation))
except IOError:
    print("Unable to read config file and load properties.")
```

[Automatically creating directories with file output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517451/automatically-creating-directories-with-file-output)

Want to create a PatientsTimelineLog.csv inside Patients Data folder in one go if it does not exist. The above link is creating the folder but the csv file is not made. makedir is used to make directory but i want inside the file in it like the path given above in dirLocation.

Comment: Look up `pathlib`

Comment: Using PurePath(dirLocation) get the name of csv file in the path. Can you guide how to make that file in new created folder Patients Data?
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dirLocation))
Above live giving none in return otherwise join can be used to concatenate file and path

Comment: Having awareness of the path is vital. I'm not at my PC now but will give an example when I can.

Comment: ok waiting for guidence

Answer (score 2):

Inside the else, you can directly use `os.makedirs(dirLocation)`.

When you use `os.path.dirname(dirLocation)` you are selecting everything except the name of the csv file. That is why you are creating only the folder.

Comment: It creates another folder inside Patient Data. But I want csv file made inside the folder.
Patient Data folder containing this file PatientsTimelineLog.csv no the filder

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    folder_path = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(dirLocation))
    sub_path = folder_path[0]
    if os.path.isdir(sub_path):
        print("Directory exist: " + dirLocation)
    else:
        print("Directory does not exists. Creating new one: " + dirLocation)
        file_name = PurePath(dirLocation)
        obj = file_name.name
        filepath = os.path.join(sub_path, obj)
        os.makedirs(sub_path)
        f = open(filepath, "a")
except IOError:
    print("Unable to read config file and load properties.")
```

This is the answer to my question. pathlib did lot of help in this question