# Url loads when accessed from the browser but not when loading from aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to load a URL from https://coinfomania.com/feed

It works perfectly when viewed from the browser
[image]

When I try to load data from the same URL with aiohttp with the following code, it gives me an error

```
from datetime import datetime
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from pathlib import Path
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import os
async def fetch_url(url, save_to_file=False):
    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=30)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout, trust_env=True) as session:
        async with session.get(url, raise_for_status=True, ssl=False) as response:
            text = await response.text()
            if save_to_file:
                current_timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S')
                name_part = urlparse(url).netloc
                # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517451/automatically-creating-directories-with-file-output
                file_name = Path(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'feeds', name_part + '_' + current_timestamp + '.rss'))
                file_name.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
                with open(file_name, 'w+') as f:
                    f.write(text)


url = 'https://coinfomania.com/feed/'
# if running inside Jupyter notebook
await fetch_url(url, save_to_file=True)
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/vr/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Users/vr/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in fetch_url
  File "/Users/vr/.local/share/virtualenvs/notebooks-dCnpXdWv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1138, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Users/vr/.local/share/virtualenvs/notebooks-dCnpXdWv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 640, in _request
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/Users/vr/.local/share/virtualenvs/notebooks-dCnpXdWv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 1004, in raise_for_status
    raise ClientResponseError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 403, message='Forbidden', url=URL('https://coinfomania.com/feed/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the website considers your request as unusual, and therefore blocks it.
You need to make it look like a normal request made from a browser by adding headers to your request.
I found a list of common headers :

```
headers= {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
}
```

To add them to your request, just change
`async with session.get(url, raise_for_status=True, ssl=False) as response:` to
`async with session.get(url, raise_for_status=True, ssl=False, headers=headers) as response:`

Comment: definitely works for this particular website, how do I know which headers to include and how do I find out the acceptable values for these headers!

Comment: From my experience, most websites only require the "User-agent" header but this one was a bit more picky. For the value of the User-agent, you can choose the value you want as long as it is a common browser. Here's a link to a user agent's repertory : https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/. Concerning the other headers, these are just some default values that browsers usually include in their requests.