# Create new folders using python

Tags: python

I am trying to create folders using the following code. Something is not correct and leads to error:

"TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

```
import os, sys

a= [4,3,2,1]
print len(a)
for idx in range (len(a)):

    newpath = r'E:\test\tool\folder_%s'(idx) 
    if not os.path.exists(newpath): os.makedirs(newpath)
```

Using os.makedirs I can create folders. However, I am not able to suffix those folders in a loop. Any ideas can be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I think you forgot a `%` after the string before `(idx)`.

Comment: Sorry. That was too dumb of me. Please disregard this question. The orignal code is big and I seem to have overlooked that % accidently got deleted

Comment: That's a pretty strange way to loop through 0,1,2,3.

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/python-best-way-to-create-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist-for-file-write since your code has a potential race condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import os, sys

a= [4,3,2,1]
print len(a)
for idx in range (len(a)):

    newpath = ((r'E:\test\tool\folder_%s') % (idx)) 
    if not os.path.exists(newpath): os.makedirs(newpath)
```

Try that, if it helps, accept the answer, if not leave a comment and I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

```
newpath = r'E:\test\tool\folder_%s' % (idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the preferred way to make strings is to use the format method.

```
newpath = 'E:\test\tool\folder_{0}'.format(idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will create the folder with name client_1001-test to client_1500-test

```
import os, sys

for i in range(1001, 1500):
    newpath = ((r'/tmp/fileSet/client_%s-test') % (i)) 
    if not os.path.exists(newpath): os.makedirs(newpath)
```