# Logging to multiple log files from different classes in Python

Tags: python, logging

I want to write a Python class which uses Python logging. This Python class will be responsible for the creating a file with a given name in init function.

I want to create a object of the above class in two or more classes and expect two or files getting generated.

I tried writing this class but I am not able to create multiple files.

Can anyone guide me how do I do that?

I have created the following class:

```
class Logger:
def __init__(self, log_filename = "test.log"):
    if not os.path.exists("LogFiles"):
        os.makedirs("LogFiles")
    self.Logger = logging.getLogger("main")
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s : %(message)s',
                        filename= log_filename,
                        filemode='w')           # change filemode to 'w' to overwrite file on each run

    consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    consoleHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
    consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.getLogger('').addHandler(consoleHandler)      # Add to the root logger
    self.Logger.info("Starting new logging sessions")


def writeToFile(self, line):
    if self.Logger.propagate == True:
        self.Logger.debug(line)

def closeFile(self):

    if self.Logger.propagate == True:
        self.Logger.propagate = False
```

Comment: [Logging to multiple destinations](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I believe that doesn't quite do what he's after; it sends output from a single logger to two locations. It also makes use of the very magic parent logging. The OP wants to send output to two different locations with independent loggers.

Comment: Here is an example solution, the trick is naming the handler.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76941199/10389449

Answer (score 81):

Sounds like the internals of your class should probably have a [`Logger`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logger-objects) and that you'll want to add a [`FileHandler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler) to the `Logger`. You might want to consider just using a factory method that creates `Logger`s and adds the handler instead of implementing your own class. You may need to create the directories that hold the log files. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/python-best-way-to-create-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist-for-file-write) for advice on creating directories.

Edit:

I don't think you need to write your own `Logger` class. Python's `logging` module has all the pieces you need. You probably just need a factory method. The key to realize is you need to create two separate, completely independent logging objects. You do this with `logging.getLogger`, and any time you pass it a different name, it gives you a different logger. You can use anything you want for the logger's name. For sure, you want to stay away from `basicConfig` for what you're doing. It's designed to be something simple for people who just want one `Logger` not doing anything too special.

I think this demonstrates the functionality you're after. The key is create two different loggers with different handlers. Then use them separately. Keep in mind that my second call to `logging.getLogger` doesn't create a new logger; it gets the one we set up initially in `setup_logger`.

log_test.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import logging

def setup_logger(logger_name, log_file, level=logging.INFO):
    l = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(message)s')
    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode='w')
    fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

    l.setLevel(level)
    l.addHandler(fileHandler)
    l.addHandler(streamHandler)    

def main():
    setup_logger('log1', r'C:\temp\log1.log')
    setup_logger('log2', r'C:\temp\log2.log')
    log1 = logging.getLogger('log1')
    log2 = logging.getLogger('log2')

    log1.info('Info for log 1!')
    log2.info('Info for log 2!')
    log1.error('Oh, no! Something went wrong!')

if '__main__' == __name__:
    main()
```

Sample run:

```
C:\temp>C:\Python\27\python.exe logtest.py
2013-06-12 02:00:13,832 : Info for log 1!
2013-06-12 02:00:13,832 : Info for log 2!
2013-06-12 02:00:13,832 : Oh, no! Something went wrong!
```

log1.log:

```
2013-06-12 02:00:13,832 : Info for log 1!
2013-06-12 02:00:13,832 : Oh, no! Something went wrong!
```

log2.log:

```
2013-06-12 02:00:13,832 : Info for log 2!
```

Comment: I am new to logging module and I see even if I am giving different filename in basicConfig there is only one file created. Let me tell what my problem is Suppose there is a class A, class B and file C. C has a main function where I create object of class A and B. Class A logs should go to A.log file and Class B log should go to B.log file. I dont want any log of A to come B.log or viceversa. So can I create a common logger class and use this class in both A and B. Any example with psuedocode would help

Comment: I have added the generic class which I wanna create. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: +1. `setup_logger()` might be a better name (getLogger() creates loggers if necessary). You might want `l.propagate = False` to avoid passing messages to ancestor loggers. Logger's name should probably be derived from a class name (a period in logger's name is special that is how logger hierarchy is created i.e., `.` in a name should be avoided unless explicitly desired (you could [use `logging_tree` to visualize it](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logging_tree))).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I think whether to use class names for the logger names depends on the usage. If it's one per class, then yes, it makes sense. If you really just have two log files and you want some classes to use one and some classes to use another, then it probably makes more sense just to use an explicit name.

Comment: What is the purpose of adding the r before the log file name?

Comment: @MakleBirt It's the file path, not the name. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/1394393).

Comment: @jpmc26 Are log1 and log2 global, or one needs to pass them as inputs to every function in the code.  I.e.,
def main():
   callFunction1() 
   callFunction2()
   etc.
def callFunction1():
   log1.info('Info for log 1!')
Notice that I didn't pass log1 as input.  It's kinda of nice to have the loggers as globals so all functions in the code are aware of it.  Maybe it's not recommendable though.. looking for recs here.  Would logging.getLogger('log1').info('hello') work?

Comment: I guess this works in the context of the question, but using this method it seems like `log1` and `log2` are now local only to `main`. Not sure how you are supposed to use this method to set up globally accessible logs.

Comment: @user5359531 Check the documentation on [`getLogger`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger).

Comment: @Dnaiel [`getLogger`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) provides global access to logging objects. I personally prefer to avoid using the global access, but using the global access is common.

Comment: @jpmc26 Awesome answer! Can you add info How to use it in different modules? 
So I create 2 loggers and now import my own module - and want to use one of loggers into it. How to do it in correct way?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Logger instances registered with `logging` are global. You do the exact same thing. You might want to look into the "inheritance" features, as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is better handled using dictConfig.  You can then specify logging to two seperate files.  I utilize the second_logger only when an API post is made so that I can log external data to the second log.

```
import os, logging
from logging.config import dictConfig

FORMAT = "%(asctime)s {app} [%(thread)d] %(levelname)-5s %(name)s - %(message)s. [file=%(filename)s:%(lineno)d]"
DATE_FORMAT = None


def setup_logging(name, level="INFO", fmt=FORMAT):
    formatted = fmt.format(app=name)
    log_dir = r'C:/log_directory'
    if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
        os.makedirs(log_dir)

    logging_config = {
        "version": 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        "formatters": {
            'standard': {
                'format': formatted
            }
        },
        "handlers": {
            'default': {
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'standard',
                'level': level,
                'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'
            },
            'file': {
                'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
                'when': 'midnight',
                'utc': True,
                'backupCount': 5,
                'level': level,
                'filename': '{}/app_manager.log'.format(log_dir),
                'formatter': 'standard',
            },
            'file2': {
                'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
                'when': 'midnight',
                'utc': True,
                'backupCount': 5,
                'level': level,
                'filename': '{}/unified_log.log'.format(log_dir),
                'formatter': 'standard',
            }
        },
        "loggers": {
            "": {
                'handlers': ['default', 'file'],
                'level': level
            },
            "second_log": {
                'handlers': ['default', 'file2'],
                'level': level
            }
        }
    }

    dictConfig(logging_config)

log.setup_logging(name="log-name", level=LEVEL
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
second_logger = logging.getLogger('second_log')
second_logger.propagate = False
```