# How to create temporary logger instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have some Python code processing incoming e-mail.  In there, there's a function `process_mail`.  While using the `logging` module from the Python3 stdlib, I would like to be able to send all log entries from one call to `process_mail` via e-mail to the original sender in case of an error.

So the question is:  How can I create temporary, throw-away logger instances at the beginning of my function, and use this to send the log back to the sender, preferably without having to read/filter the log file?  At the same time, all entries should go to my normal logs.

Comment: Is the logging module's [SMTPHandler](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.handlers.html#smtphandler) what you're looking for, by any chance?

Comment: @nlsdfnbch in principle yes, but I cannot figure out how to group log messages into one single email and not send a mail each time the logger is used.

Comment: create a logger within the function, attach a separate `FileHandler` and pass that file's path to `process_mail` and send via attachment?

Comment: I had a similar issue this provided me with hints https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035077/logging-to-multiple-log-files-from-different-classes-in-python