# setup.py script , how to install packages to custom directory?

Tags: python, installation, distutils

How to install my packages to alternative directory (ex. /opt/myapp) instead of the usual third party python path ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/create-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist-for-file-write?rq=1 -- does this discussion answer your question?

Comment: thanks for your time , the answer is "no" , I expect that the script should create this directories and copy the modules into it.

Comment: Please read the documentation of package_dir.  package_dir is not the destination.  Package_dir is to tell distutils where your packages are in your source tree.

Comment: thanks for notification , I read it quickly , so I wrongly understand it , what is the option for distination directory ??

Answer (score 3):

I have found this way which is accepted for me :

> 1/ Make setup configuration file .
>
> 2/ Add the following to the configuration file :

```
[install]
install-base=    # custom path
install-purelib= # custom path
install-platlib= # add custom path
install-scripts=  # add custom path
install-data=      # add custom path 
install-headers=    #add custom path
```

this is better than force the user to specify them in the command line, in addition he can override this conf. from the command line .
It works fine for me .