# File Uploads data

Tags: django, django-models

I have a excel file with various columns and rows. I upload this file and saves the data
in the database.But i am having a problem and need help in figuring out this issue :-

1) Upload the file with the same name but with different contents uploads the previous file data.

So let say i upload abc.xls having 3 rows it uplods 3 rows but if i upload the another file with 10 rows having the same name abc.xls it shows the result of previously uploaded file and displays only 3 results.

I tried unique files like but then i have No such File or Directory.

```
# Models.py
    class ExcelFile(models.Model):

        excel_file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'ExcelFile'
            verbose_name_plural = 'ExcelFiles'


        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.excel_file.name
```

In the admin i see the files are already unique like abc_1.xls, abc_2.xls and so on.
Here is my code

```
   #views.py
   if request.method == "POST":
            form_data = ImportExcelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form_data.is_valid():
                cd = form_data.cleaned_data
                file_obj, created = ExcelFile.objects.get_or_create(excel_file=cd['excel_file'])
                try:
                    data_list = excel_parser(cd['excel_file'].name.replace(" ", "_"))
                except:
                    data_list = excel_parser(get_correct_filename(cd['excel_file']))
########### and so on #######################

def get_correct_filename(filename):
    replacements = {"(": "", ")": ""," ":"_"}
    new_file = "".join(replacements.get(c, c) for c in filename.name)
    return new_file


def excel_parser(filename):
    """
    Excel file will first come here. It will be read sheetwise.
    This functions will return a data list.
    """

    file_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'documents/' + filename
    #Here it is reading abc.xls only as the filename is abc.xls
    book = open_workbook(file_path)
    data_list = []
    sheet_list = []

    total_sheets = book.nsheets
    for sheet in range(total_sheets):
        sheet_counter = book.sheet_by_index(sheet)
        data_list = extract_data(book,sheet)
        sheet_list.append(data_list)
    return sheet_list
```

Comment: how do you handle uploads?

Comment: you can see my code now it picks the same file though it is uploading unique files on the db

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the directory 'uploads/logos' into the media directory. You could do it manually or automatically:

[How to check if a directory exists and create it if necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/create-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist-for-file-write)

Comment: Directory already created. everything is working but the problem if i upload the a file twice having the same filename it picks the previous file

Comment: have you set the MEDIA_ROOT variable in the settings file?

Comment: Actually you dont need to create any of the media folders. Django will automatically create them as needed.