# creating directories from for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, directory

I need to create directories from for loop.  I have a list.

```
a = [banana 1234, apple 456, orange 789]
```

And I need to create folders named by the numbers that are ending with numbers in list. for example.

```
C:\folder\1234; C:\folder\456
```

and so on.

code is

```
for length in atrinkta:
folder = re.findall(r'\d{9,}', length)
os.makedirs("D:/python_study/images/skelbimai/" + folder)
```

but I get an error **"TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects"** don't know what to do. Please someone help.

**EDIT**
I tried your method 2nd time. After deleting created folder for whatever reason python gives me error

```
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'D:/python_study/images/skelbimai/'
```

**2ndEdit**

shaktimaan, now i get other error **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'**. What does this mean?

Comment: You asked on my answer (which I deleted) how to avoid creating a dir that already exists (or was already created).  [Just check if the directory exists before creating it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\d+')
>>> a = ['banana 1234', 'apple 456', 'orange 789']
>>> for item in a:
...     dir_name = 'D:/python_study/images/skelbimai/{}'.format(re.search(pattern, item).group(0))
...     if not os.path.isdir(dir_name):
...         os.mkdir(dir_name)
```

This is how it works. The regex finds the numbers in each of the elements of the list. You cah check it by doing:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\d+')
>>> a = ['banana 1234', 'apple 456', 'orange 789']
>>> for item in a:
...     print re.search(pattern, item).group(0)
...
'1234'
'456'
'789'
```

You just concatenate your base directory with each of the numbers calculated as above and call `os.mkdir` on each. Since you are creating directory in the loop, you do not need `makedirs`

Comment: ok. VERY COOL. But if numbers are repeat and I get and error that folder is already created. How to evade that? :/ You see the numbers in list seem to repeat.

Comment: I get an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'"

Comment: @user3383245 I made a change in `dir_name`. It shows no error for me. Are my list `a` and your list the same?

Comment: That was probably because file contained few "\n". But when I used other file without "\n". It created only two folders instead of 19. And throws no error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for length in atrinkta:
    folder = re.search(r'(\d+)', length)
    os.makedirs("D:/python_study/images/skelbimai/" + folder.groups()[0])
```