# File does not exist error with 'w' mode

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am encountering an odd behaviour from the `file()` builtin. I am using the unittest-xml-reporting Python package to generate results for my unit tests. Here are the lines that open a file for writing, a file which (obviously does not exist):

```
report_file = file('%s%sTEST-%s.xml' % \
                (test_runner.output, os.sep, suite), 'w')
```

(code is taken from the package's [Github page](https://github.com/danielfm/unittest-xml-reporting/blob/1.3/src/xmlrunner/__init__.py#L239))

However, I am given the following error:

```
...
File "/home/[...]/django-cms/.tox/pytest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xmlrunner/__init__.py", line 240, in generate_reports
(test_runner.output, os.sep, suite), 'w')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './TEST-cms.tests.page.NoAdminPageTests.xml'
```

I found this weird because, as the Python docs state, if the `w` mode is used, the file should be created if it doesn't exist. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Why do use [file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file)?: "When opening a file, it’s preferable to use [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) instead of invoking this constructor directly."

Comment: I've specified I am using a package, and that code belongs to that package (I've provided a link for further info). I can't change the contents of the package :)

Comment: please run it under `strace` to see what this program is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the file which needed to be created was attempted to be created in a directory that has already been deleted (since the path was given as `.` and most probably the test directory has been deleted by that point).

I managed to fix this by supplying an absolute path to `test_runner.output` and the result files are successfully created now.

Answer (score 2):

from `man 2 read`

```
   ENOENT O_CREAT  is  not  set  and the named file does not exist.  Or, a
          directory component in pathname does not exist or is a  dangling
          symbolic link.
```

take your pick :)

in human terms:

- your current working directory, `./` is removed by the time this command is ran,
- `./TEST-cms.tests.page.NoAdminPageTests.xml` exists but is a symlink pointing to nowhere
- "w" in your open/file call is somehow messed up, e.g. if you redefined `file` builtin

Comment: If I open a Python console, creating that file works...: `>>> f = file('./TEST-cms.tests.page.NoAdminPageTests.xml', 'w')
>>> f
<open file './TEST-cms.tests.page.NoAdminPageTests.xml', mode 'w' at 0x7f3477e0cf60>
`

Answer (score 2):

`file` will create a file, but not a directory. You have to create it first, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary)

Comment: Check the link I've provided to the package's full code. The directories are created some steps before the lines I've posted.