# Error while executing os.getcwd()?

Tags: python

I encountered a rather weird problem to me. I stepped into some tests to debug what's going wrong, and when I try to find the current working directory, I get the following error:

```
ipdb> os.getcwd()
*** OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What's the problem and how can I view the current working directory?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your current working directory *no longer exists*:

```
$ mkdir deleteme
$ cd deleteme/
$ ../bin/python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Apr 28 2014, 17:17:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/deleteme'
>>> ^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ../bin/python
$ cd ..
$ rmdir deleteme
$ fg
../bin/python   (wd: ~/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/deleteme)

>>> os.getcwd()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The work-around is could be to change your working directory to one that exists, with `os.chdir()`:

```
>>> os.chdir('/tmp')
>>> os.getcwd()
'/private/tmp'
```

but if you encounter this in a test suite, then that test suite was using a temporary working directory that has since been cleaned up.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. Please see the related issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870057/file-does-not-exist-error-with-w-mode. I am trying to see why opening that file throws the exception, so I thought viewing _where_ the script is running is important (since the file path is given as a relative path). I don't believe the cwd is deleted since it should be the dir from where tests are run (meaning, the package's dir).

Comment: @AndreiHorak: but it *isn't*. The `os.getcwd()` function is nothing more than a wrapper around the C call of the same name, which returns an error if the process current working dir points to a location that doesn't exist. Because the working dir is only settable to a location that does exist *at that time*, that must mean that it *no longer exists* by the time you call `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Alright, then you must be right. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. Managed to do a small fix to my original issue and things started to move to the right direction. Cheers!