# Programmatically write contents of a list to a directory

Tags: python, file-io

I have a python list `['a','b','c']` that's generated inside a for loop. I would like to write each element of the list to a new file.

I have tried:

```
counter = 0
for i in python_list:
    outfile = open('/outdirectory/%s.txt') % str(counter) 
    outfile.write(i)
    outfile.close()
    counter += 1
```

I get an error:

```
IOError: [Erno 2] No suchfile or directory.
```

How can I programmatically create and write files in a for loop?

Comment: Does the directory `/outdirectory` exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing a mode to open, so it's trying to open in read mode.

```
outfile = open('/outdirectory/%s.txt' % str(counter), "w")
```

Try this:

```
out_directory = "/outdirectory"
if not os.path.exists(out_directory):
    os.makedirs(out_directory)

for counter in range(0, len(python_list)):
    file_path = os.path.join(out_directory, "%s.txt" % counter)
    with open(file_path, "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(python_list[counter])
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to python and overlooked the open mode.

Comment: NP, please check out the other answers that are suggesting additional improvements,  I have posted a more complete example

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- Use the `with` statement for handling the files
  [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).
- Use the correct file open mode for writing [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).
- You can only create files in directories that actually exist. Your error message probably indicates that the call to `open()` fails, probably because the directory does not exist. Either you have a typo in there, or you need to create the directory first (e.g., as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273192/1025391)).

Example:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i, data in enumerate(l):
    fname = 'outdirectory/%d.txt' % i
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

basically the message you get is because you try to open a file named `/outdirectory/%s.txt`.  A following error as ErlVolton show is that you don't open your file in writing mode. additionaly you must check that you directory exist. if you use `/outdirectory` it means from the root of the file system.

Three pythonic additional:
- enumerate iterator which autocount the item in your list
- with statement autoclose your file.
- format can be a little clearer than % thing

so the code could be written in the following

```
for counter,i in enumerate(python_list):
    with open('outdirectory/{}.txt'.format(counter),"w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(i)
```

PS: next time show the full back trace

Comment: Thanks, I had never seen enumerate before. Looks like a neat trick.