# Creating a missing directory / file structure - Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a function that does some operations with a `.log` file: The program checks if `/logs/ansible.log` exists before proceeding. If `/logs/ansible.log` doesn't exist, it should go ahead and create the file / directory structure (both don't exist prior).

```
try:
  if not os.path.exists("/logs/ansible.log"):
     # create the /logs/ansible.log file
finally:
  # do something
```

I know I can create the `ansible.log` file with `open('ansible.log', 'w')` and create the directory with `os.makedirs('/logs/')`, however how can I simply create `'/logs/ansible.log'` at once?

*** Assume program is being executed as `root`

Comment: `os.makedirs('/logs')`

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/in-python-check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary

Comment: @fiacre I already know that ... I want to create `/logs/ansible.log` at once ... see how I referred to that in the question

Comment: python or not, the OS will not create all at once...

Comment: But, that is not possible in shell -- if /logs does not exists you can't create /logs/ansible.log with a single command.  As with shell, in python you have to create directory first *then* create the file.

Answer (score 6):

```
def createAndOpen(filename, mode):
     os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path), exist_ok=True)
     return open(filename, mode)
```

Now, you can open the file and create the folder at once:

```
with createAndOpen('/logs/ansible.log', 'a') as f:
    f.write('Hello world')
```

Otherwise, this isn’t possible. The operating system does not give you a single function that does this, so whatever else existed that does this would have to have a similar logic as above. Just less visible to you. But since it simply doesn’t exist, you can just create it yourself.