# Workflow to create a folder if it doesn't exist already

Tags: python

In [this interesting thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/in-python-check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary), the users give some options to create a directory if it doesn't exist.

The answer with most votes it's obviously the most popular, I guess because its the shortest way:

```
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
```

The function included in the 2nd answer seems more robust, and in my opinion the best way to do it.

```
import os
import errno

def make_sure_path_exists(path):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
    except OSError as exception:
        if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise
```

So I was wondering, what does people do in their scripts? Type 2 lines just to create a folder? Or even worst, copy, and paste the function `make_sure_path_exists` in every script that needs to create a folder?

I'd expect that such a wide spread programming language as Python would already have a library with includes a similar function.

The other 2 programming languages that I know, which are more like scripting languages, can do this with ease.

Bash: `mkdir -p path`

Powershell: `New-Item -Force path`

Please don't take this question as a rant against Python, because it's not intended to be like that.

I'm planing to learn Python to write scripts where 90% of the time I'll have to create folders, and I'd like to know what is the most productive way to do so.

I really think I'm missing something about Python.

Comment: In Python 3, `os.makedirs()` has a kwarg "exist_ok". See here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py#L216

Answer (score 6, accepted):

make a module with `make_sure_path_exists` defined in it. import it when needed.

Answer (score 24):

you can use the below

```
# file handler
import os
filename = "./logs/mylog.log"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: The answer is correct, but please make sure if similar answers already exist. In this case, a mention about "exist_ok" is already posted in a comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123394/workflow-to-create-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-exist-already/67060756#comment52139211_32123394

Comment: @KasiaGauza But the comments aren't answers, and the op cannot accept a comment as an answer, sooooo what is wrong with his complete answer in this case?

Comment: I think you're right, even if the author of the question accepted the answer in the comment

Comment: @Sinux1 the most correct way would probably to mark it as Community Wiki answer. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343086/why-would-you-mark-an-answer-as-community-wiki for more details

Answer (score 2):

This is a question of [idempotence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) and none of the current answers provide a clear explanation on how to make `os.makedirs` idempotent and many are superfluous. Here’s a clear answer with minimal examples:

## Python 3

We simply set the `exist_ok` flag to `True` (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)).

#### A Working Example

```
import os

directory = “my/test/directory/”

os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok = True)
```

## Python 2

As mentioned in the original question, we can manually handle when a directory already exists by using a conditional and the `os.path.exists` method (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)) to check:

#### A Working Example

```
import os

directory = “my/test/directory/”

if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
```

---

The above examples are both idempotent and, after multiple executions, you should get no error related to the directory already existing.

Comment: For your Python 3 example you should have exist_ok, not exists_ok.

Answer (score 1):

Getting help from different answers I produced this code

```
if not os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + '/' + folderName):
    os.makedirs(os.getcwd() + '/' + folderName, exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Why have the `exist_ok` flag set to `True` if you're checking that it doesn't in fact exist already in the conditional?

Comment: Valid point. Can you make the edit if you have tested it?

Comment: I’ll be more direct — the conditional is redundant and adds no value. Both it and the `exists_ok` flag effectively make the `makedirs` operation idempotent, much like adding the `-p` flag to `mkdir` when doing the same operation on a Unix system.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def main():
    dirName = 'C:/SANAL'

    # Create target directory & all intermediate directories if don't exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(dirName)    
        print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
    except FileExistsError:
        print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

f = open('C:/SANAL/merhabadünya.txt','w')
for i in range (10):
        f.write('MERHABA %d\r\n' % (i+1))

f.close()

f = open('C:/SANAL/merhabadünya.txt','r')
message = f.read()
print(message)

f.close()
```

Comment: An example for creating a directory or skip creating if exists. Also shows to use write, read and using 'for' statement.