# Can't evaluate if folder exist python

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm trying to check if a path exists so it creates it if it doesn't exist but it always runs despite the folder existing. i.e. evaluating to false:

```
if not os.path.isdir(('thumnail\\' + folderName).replace('\\', '/')):
    os.makedirs('thumbnail\\' + folderName)
```

Whats the correct way to do this. I've tried  using path.exists, changing the escaped '\' to '/' and not doing it but its always false.

Comment: You should probably use full paths and not relative paths.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically creating directories with file output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517451/automatically-creating-directories-with-file-output)

Comment: Though I prefer the `try/except` method [from this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123394/workflow-to-create-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-exist-already)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Workflow to create a folder if it doesn't exist already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32123394/8150685)

Comment: Syntatical Remorse, what do you mean. Its evaluating the xamp web directory as the root so I think this is the full path.

Comment: `'thumnail\\'` is a relative path. Meaning from where I am running this script look into the `thumnail` directory for my `folderName`.

Comment: 'thumnail\\' isn't where the script is bring run from. the script is nowhere in that path.

Comment: I don't think you understand how relative paths works when you are running a python script.... You may want to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416072/reading-file-using-relative-path-in-python-project/40416154)

Comment: You're checking for a different directory name than the one being created -- `thumnail` vs. `thumbnail`.  Is this intentional?

Comment: John Gordon, yeah that was the issue. I copy pasted the mkdir line and printed the evaluation for that. That's why I was seeing it as correct syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

To check path validity in python use

```
os.path.exists('Absolute or Relative path of directory or file')
```

the problem with your code maybe that 'thumnail\' isn't an absolute path or relative path, in that format it maybe referring to the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using windows that's why you are using backward slash (\).
It will work fine if you use forward slash as well (/)

Also, there is one spelling mistake **thumnail** and if you are using forward slash in the first line then use it same for second as well.

```
if not os.path.isdir(('thumbnail\\' + folderName).replace('\\', '/')):
    os.makedirs(('thumbnail\\' + folderName).replace('\\', '/'))
```

Also, try using python Pathlib package to make your code windows Linux environment independent.

There is a great tutorial here. - https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/

if you are windows make string raw type to avoid conflict with a backward slash as a escape character like this r'thumbnail\'