# Moving images to a new folder with shutil ends up in replacing this folder with the files I was moving

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, shutil

I want to move an image of dogs and cats from the `train` directory into two directories `train/dogs` and `train/cats` to be ready to use PyTorch's ImageFolder function. However when done without `/` at the end of the new directories it seems that instead of moving the files to the new train/dogs folder for example it moves the image to a train/dogs file

```
# we move dogs to train/dogs and cats to train/cats
import re

train_dir = "train"
train_dogs_dir = f'{train_dir}/dogs'
train_cats_dir = f'{train_dir}/cats'

files = os.listdir(train_dir)

for f in files: 
    catSearchObj = re.search("cat", f)
    dogSearchObj = re.search("dog", f)
    if catSearchObj:
        shutil.move(f'{train_dir}/{f}', train_cats_dir)
    elif dogSearchObj:
        shutil.move(f'{train_dir}/{f}', train_dogs_dir)
```

Indeed, after that when he did `! the train/dogs` answers me:

```
train/dogs
```

And with `! cat train/dogs`:

```
����JFIF��C



#%$""!&+7/&)4)!"0A149;>>>%.DIC<H7=>;��C
;("(;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;��w�"��   
���}!1AQa"q2��#B��R��$3br�  
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`shutil` docs for `move()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)  say "If the destination is an ***existing*** directory, then src is moved inside that directory." *(emphasis added)*

Is it possible your target directories don't exist?

You may need to [create those directories if they don't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67060756/5590742).